# Avoid pass-phrase prompt on git push to remote

Tags: git, ssh

When I created my SSH key while setting up git, I chose to use a pass-phrase for the key.  Now, whenever I push to my remote repository (unfuddle), I get prompted for this pass-phrase.  Is there some way to automate this?

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [SSH Agent](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh).

Answer (score 4):

Use ssh-agent: http://wiki.sourcemage.org/Git_Guide#I.27m_tired_of_typing_my_SSH_key_passphrase.

You can get more information from this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595863/3978).

Comment: @Nuzzolilo I've updated the link - although I suspect there are other better guides available.