# How can I perform a `git pull` without re-entering my SSH password?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, github

Is it possible to configure `git/ssh` so I don't have to enter my passphrase every time I want to perform a `git pull`?   Note that the repo is a private one on github.

Or, alternatively, what would be the best practice to automate code deployment from a private Github repo?

**Additional details:** EC2 instance running a public AMI based on Fedora.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuring Git over SSH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh)

Comment: You have solution of this problem ?

Comment: As of git 2.11+ (Q4 2016) using libsecret is another way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312117/8477066

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Have a look at this link https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/

> **But I don’t want to enter a long passphrase every time I use the key!**
>
> Neither do I! Thankfully, there’s a nifty little tool called
>   `ssh-agent` that can save your passphrase securely so you don’t have
>   to re-enter it. If you’re on OSX Leopard or later your keys can be
>   saved in the system’s keychain to make your life even easier. Most
>   linux installations will automatically start ssh-agent for you when
>   you log in.

Comment: This link was helpful in explaining what commands to run in order to get your passphrase saved in `ssh-agent`: http://rabexc.org/posts/using-ssh-agent

Comment: I dont want use keys. Simple i have user\pass and i want save it on git client side

Comment: Why does the link only provide Mac/Widows options? I want to git pull on the unix server without reentering the pass. managed to make it work for a historic project but cant tell what I did there. Is the point that when you ssh to a remote unix machine the key is passed on and that is used as a git pull (or private composer vcs) key instead? I believe I'm misunderstanding something here. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 45):

I enabled the password caching as described here:

https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-linux

To cache the password for a month:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=2628000'
```

Comment: Thanks, temuri- I've been looking everywhere for this exact detail. It wasn't working, but the documentation seemingly doesn't mention it is only for HTTPS.

Comment: If you use a password (**not** a passphrase with key file) for an SSH-based URL of a remote Git repo, you cannot save the password at all. But I noticed that after issuing any git command, you can **immediately type the password and press Enter**. You don't need to wait for the password prompt to appear.

Comment: git still ask pass

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

`git config credential.helper store`

You'll have to enter your password once, after that it is stored in a folder inside root.

As comments pointed out, **This does NOT work for SSH passwords, only for HTTPS passwords.**

Comment: @nim That doesn't mean you should downvote the answer, I've suggested what worked for me, and someone might find it helpful.

Comment: It's no save password. I Try it and nothing result. If you remote like this ssh://name@ip/path

Comment: This works if you're looking to store the HTTP basic auth password.

Comment: This does NOT work for SSH passwords, only for HTTPS passwords.

Comment: works nice for https. You just need to type this in. Next time should be the last time you need to enter the paraphrase. The next next time, the password should be remembered by git.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for SSH links?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky This doesn't work for SSH, you might wanna try something else from the other answers

Comment: for everything to be ok I use the "git config credential.helper store" and then I trigger the push or pull and after that git no longer asks for the password.

Answer (score 13):

I dont know why hasnt anyone reported this yet. But the simplest approach would be to simply add a single line `AddKeysToAgent yes` on the top of the .ssh/config file. Ofcourse `ssh-agent` must be running beforehand. If its not running ( check by the command `ssh-agent` on the terminal ) , then simply run it `eval $(ssh-agent)`

I can confirm that this works, because in my project with lots of submodules and for each submodule being cloned, I had to type in my ssh passphrase. After the above trick, I dont need to do it anymore.

The source of the solution is https://askubuntu.com/questions/362280/enter-ssh-passphrase-once/853578#853578

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer. Further, to have ssh-agent running one can use a systemd user service

Comment: I've been searching for far too long, and this finally worked.

Answer (score 6):

Your situation is now fixed, however for me it was the fact that I had more than one key in `~/.ssh/`

To resolve the problem I had to create a file called `~/.ssh/config` and add the line:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_key2_rsa
```

where `~/.ssh/my_key2_rsa` is my key.

Comment: Thanks for this, my `id_rsa`  and `id_rsa.pub` files have a custom name which is why git would never recognize it.

ref: https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

Answer (score 3):

I updated my ~/.ssh/config file to read the following, and no longer have to enter my ssh password.

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Comment: `Bad configuration option: usekeychain`

Comment: I got the same error as @crypdick in my Ubuntu, but not on macOS.

Comment: Solution to this error is here- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47455373/737440

Answer (score 2):

open (or create) the ~/.ssh/config file and add these lines to the file:

```
Host *
UseKeychain yes
```

Source: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/