# How to run git pull and bypass SSH passphrase prompt in user startup script?

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

This is on Ubuntu, I have a user startup shell script that runs every time the instance boots (EC2 via `--user-data-file` argument). I want to have the instance do a git pull from a specific branch every time it boots. The problem is when I do a git pull, there is a SSH key passphrase prompt and I am not sure what the best way is to automatically enter the password in a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Expect http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect
it will allow you to provide password to interactive ssh session

Comment: Thanks, this might work. Although I'll have to put the passphrase in the plain text, so I might as well just remove the passphrase from the ssh key. I also found some more secure alternatives, but they seem more involved. Anyway, I'll accept this answer in the meantime. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should generate your public ssh key and ask the administrator of that branch to store the key in his authorized_keys file.

This is what you should do:
[Generating Your SSH Public Key](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key)

This is what the administrator should do:
[How to Use RSA Key for SSH Authentication](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Use-RSA-Key-for-SSH-Authentication-38599.shtml)

Comment: Yang, I am pulling from beanstalk. I don't think they let you add your own key to autorhized_keys

Comment: Does ssh-agent help? See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265595/how-can-i-peform-a-git-pull-without-re-entering-my-ssh-password)

Comment: I saw that post, I'm not sure if that'll work coz in the script I'll need to start ssh-agent and run ssh-add, which will prompt for passphrase and we are back to square one :)