# Git push says - The requested URL returned error: 403 but with sudo - works

Tags: git, ubuntu, permissions, push, sudo

If i use command

```
git push
```

It says fatal: unable to access 'http://***.git The requested URL returned error: 403
If i add sudo sudo git push it works fine. 
Where should i add permissions?

I tried

```
sudo find /var/www/.git -type d -exec chmod 0777 {} +
```

And

```
sudo find /var/www/.git -type f -exec chmod 0777 {} +
```

But it only helps me to commit from my user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my ip changed(local) when i get new computer. Previously in our company was corporate proxy.
So i entered:

```
export https_proxy=""
export http_proxy=""
```

And add in your local repository folder

```
 sudo chown -R YourUserName .git/
```

if you need to clone project in folders such var from user
use

```
 sudo find /var/ -type d -exec chmod 0777 {} +
 sudo find /var/ -type f -exec chmod 0777 {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

403 is a permission error returned by the server, not your local workstation, so no amount of chmod 777 will change that.

Check your credential helper: `git config credential.helper`: chances you have one defined when you type that command as you (not as `root` with `sudo`)

It could be [gnome-keyring (now obsolete) or git-credential-libsecret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312117/6309). Or store.

Try first, for testing, [to unset it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240995/6309), then push again: it should query for your credentials (GitHub username/password). Check if the push succeeds.

Comment: Yeap i agree with you. But it says 403 error. Look like a bug. When i change 777 it allow me to commit. Push allow with sudo.

Comment: @PashukxCode Is the remote server one you control, or a remote Git repos hosting server like github.com or gitlab.com?

Comment: Nope...I think may be i make rsa key from sudo...for http...or something like that.

Comment: It happens when i change my computer to new one. And save Hard disk.

Comment: @PashukxCode Yes, it is important to *not* use sudo, but only your local Linux account, when working with Git, in order to use your associate credentials (like a ~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub) key).