# How to apply git fetch through netrc.gpg file to crontab

Tags: git, cron

i am currently planning to register and utilize the git repository in redmine.

Because redmine is not managed through remote url, there was a problem that you had to git clone it and leave the fetch periodically.

It could have been handled simply through the git `credential store`, but I decided there was a security problem, so I encrypted the netrc file with the netrc.gpg file and then made the git-credential-netrc file fetch through `git.credential = netrc -v`.

These tasks were written after seeing the reference materials below.

1. [is-there-a-way-to-cache-github-credentials-for-pushing-commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-cache-github-credentials-for-pushing-commits/18362082#18362082)
2. [whats-the-best-encrypted-git-credential-helper-for-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305965/whats-the-best-encrypted-git-credential-helper-for-linux)

In particular, I referred to the reference number 1, and I also checked that the shell script works normally when it is turned locally after making the shell script as below.

- update-git-repo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ${PROJECT_DIR}

for entry in `ls -d */`
    do
        echo "$entry"
        cd ${entry}  && {
                git remote update
                cd ..
            }
    done
```

- correct result

[image]

However, there was a problem when turning this shell script file into crontab to operate it periodically.

- crontab -e

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
 */1 * * * * /home/vanilla/redmine/docker-redmine/update-git-repo.sh >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
```

- cron.log

[image]

At first, I thought it would be a user permission issue, but the shell script worked fine when it was operated by a user named `vanilla`, and I checked the crontab file of the user with `crontab -e -u vanilla` and confirmed that it was in the file.

What's the problem?

I am attaching a link to the file in the git-credential-netrc I used, although I don't know if it can help.

[git-credential-netrc.perl](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/credential/netrc/git-credential-netrc.perl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very simple problem.
I changed the git global credential option as below and it was solved.

```
git config --global credential.helper /usr/local/bin/git-credential-netrc
```

In running local shell script, it works as a `git config --global credential.helper "netrc -v"` command, but in the case of crontab, the location of the actual command must be specified and registered as credential due to environmental variables or other problems.

https://gist.github.com/soardex/bd588f633d03d8bd0f84