# How to manage a repo on a shared computer?

Tags: git, ssh-keys

We have a shared computer (hooked up to hardware) that multiple developers use for testing code and pulling/pushing commits. A couple common problems we encounter are:

1. Unable to use a use a git global user.name and user.email since we want each commit tagged to the appropriate developer. We have a decent work around using the --author tag eg.

   ```
   git commit --author="foo@bar.net" -m "Fixes from the bug"
   ```
2. The more annoying issue is around pushing from this shared repo to github. We currently use tokens and set the remote as `https`. However these token need to be copy pasted each time and becomes cumbersome.

What is a better way to handle this situation?

Now I understand that with git command we can specify the ssh key to be used with a `-i` flag. However, I'd rather not store all users keys on the same machine. Is it instead possible to provide key from a remote file.
eg. A developer is logged in from their laptop to the shared machine via ssh, so when running git commands is there a way to source the ssh key from the laptop.

Comment: That just sounds like a security and accountability disaster waiting to happen. Why can't you have individual user accounts, at least? What OS is this? What is "hardware"?

Comment: Sharing a computer does not (and should not) mean sharing login credentials. Why doesn't each developer have their own account on the shared machine?

Comment: Maybe developers should be making code changes on their local laptops, and the shared hardware should be a "deploy only" machine? That is, nobody ever edits files on the shared machine and there is never any need to push changes from there.

Comment: The OS is linux.  Separate accounts is a possibility but a number of software on the shared machine runs as services which makes switching users tricky. The hardware is sensors, camera and other robotics stuff which cannot be easily moved around.
Note, the shared computer is not used for direct development, but for testing.  Sometime testing uncovers a fix that then needs to be uploaded.

Comment: Commit fix on development device, push from development device, pull on testing device. Assuming there’s a build step of some kind, you can even make the pull part part of that automated process.

Comment: If you cannot create an account for each user, ask the users to clone their own copies of the remote repositories. In their own repositories, set configuration values of their own in the local level like `user.name` and `user.email`. For authentications, you can manage the usernames and passwords/tokens with the help of credential helpers like [libsecret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53307245/6330106) so that the users don't have to input manually and that the passwords/tokens are not leaked.