# Repository with git-credential-libsecret binaries for CentOS 7?

Tags: git, centos7, git-credential-manager

I am trying to store my git credentials securely on my CentOS 7 machine using `git-credential-libsecret` without success, migrating from the insecure `git-credential-store`.

#### TLDR;

I cannot find any prebuilt binaries of `git-credential-libsecret` for CentOS 7. I would like to ask if anyone can link me to a repository that provides them, before resorting back to build from source.

Using Git 2.22.0 from IUS repo:

```
[XXX@YYY ~]# git --version
git version 2.22.0
```

`credential.helper` has been pointed to `libsecret`:

```
[XXX@YYY ~]# git config --list --show-origin
file:/home/XXX/.gitconfig   credential.helper=libsecret
```

Running `git pull` on a private repo prints this:

```
[XXX@YYY Foo-repo]# git pull
git: 'credential-libsecret' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Confirming that `git-credential-libsecret` is indeed not installed:

```
[XXX@YYY ~]# sudo ls /usr/libexec/git-core/ | grep credential
git-credential
git-credential-cache
git-credential-cache--daemon
git-credential-store
```

Active repositories:

```
base centos-sclo-rh centos-sclo-sclo elrepo epel extras ius remi-safe updates
```

Trying to install `git-credential-libsecret`:

```
[XXX@YYY ~]# sudo dnf provides git-credential-libsecret
Error: No Matches found
```

---

It seems like some other distros (e.g. Fedora) ships with repository that provides `git-credential-libsecret` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312117/5637701)), but not CentOS. I feel wary about installing from Fedora repo due to compatibility concerns.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Git 2.22.0 from IUS repo:

The [IUS git222 package](https://github.com/iusrepo/git222) was forked from the [Fedora git package](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/git).  It follows the same layout, with a minimal set of functionality in the git222-core package, and the rest of the functionality (and all their dependencies) in the main git222 package.  The file you are looking for is `/usr/libexec/git-core/git-credential-libsecret`.

```
# repoquery --whatprovides /usr/libexec/git-core/git-credential-libsecret | grep git222 | sort -V | tail -1
git222-0:2.22.4-1.el7.ius.x86_64
```

You can resolve this by installing the full git222 package.

```
# yum install git222
```

> I feel wary about installing from Fedora repo due to compatibility concerns.

As you should, installing packages compiled for a different distribution typically breaks your system.

Comment: I tried installing this package but still don't see the binary installed. `Updated: git222.x86_64 0:2.22.3-2`