# How to store multiple PATs/passwords for use by git?

Tags: linux, git, passwords, git-credential-manager

### One password is no problem

I wanted to store my credentials "safely" for use by `git` so I did as instructed
[here](https://askubuntu.com/a/959662/443958). This way I don't have to input password/PAT every single time, I perform any git operation.

1. Install `libsecret` using `sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev`
2. Build the "credential manager" using `sudo make --directory=/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret`
3. and then configure my local git folder using `git config --global credential.helper \ /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret`

Works superb.

### How to do the above with many passwords?

What I don't get is **how to do the same for many passwords** associated
with different accounts/repositories. I was suggested to use gcm core.

I tried installing `gcm core` as instructed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core).

1. Download .deb package
2. `sudo dpkg -i <path-to-package> git-credential-manager-core configure`
3. configure the "credential store" `git config credential.credentialStore secretservice` (as I use libsecret).
4. I removed the `Credential helper` pointing to
   `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret`
   from the local git config file.

**It still doesn't work.** When I try to push a repo, I get a garbled
message with how to use `git config` followed by request to fill in
credentials (shown [here](https://pastebin.com/K1Lqt7tX)).  I don't understand what I am doing! namely `credential store`, `credential manager`, `secret-service` and `gcm core`.

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312117/5986651) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505417/5986651) and I still don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any credential helper should follow the same process.

But if you have multiple account/password for the same domain (say github.com for instance), then you need to change your remote URL

```
 cd /path/to/my/local/repo1
 git remote set-url origin https://user1@github.com/user1/myRepo1
                                   ^^^^^^

 cd /path/to/my/local/repo2
 git remote set-url origin https://user2@github.com/user1/myRepo2
                                   ^^^^^^
```

That way, the credential helper will differentiate your different account.
Since gcm core is a bit fineky to install, test it first with the classic libsecret-based helper.

Comment: I tried it, but I still get the same garbled output followed by request to type password (not username though). When I type the password, it doesn't end up saving it.

Comment: What does it mean to "test it first with classic libsecret-based helper"?

Comment: @agent18 The first part of your question, the one ending with "Works superb.": test it with that.

Comment: Just did... So the old repo which worked before still continues to work. Here the local git config `credential.helper` points to `libsecret/git-credential-libsecret`. Still works with the same "garbled error" (as shown [here](https://pastebin.com/K1Lqt7tX))

Comment: @agent18 What version of Git are you using? show-scope is Git 2.26 (Q1 2020): https://stackoverflow.com/a/60286340/6309

Comment: 2.25.1 is the version number.

Comment: Am I using an advanced version of GCM core?

Comment: @GCM core might be using an option of Git 2.26+. Can you upgrade first Git to 2.31.1? (http://lifeonubuntu.com/upgrading-ubuntu-to-use-the-latest-git-version/)

Comment: Bro Hearty thanks. YOU DID IT. It is because of people like you that I can still use linux albeit strugglingly.

IT WORKS. I needed two things: 1 is `git remote set-url origin https://user1@github.com/user1/myRepo1.git` and the other is `git 2.31`.  This seems to have done the trick... for both my usernames. I will update the answers. :) THANKS A TON.