# AWS best method to ssh between EC2 instances in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have my NAT and Bastion set up to login with SSH forwarding:

```
ssh-add -K keyfile.pem
ssh -A ec2-user@bastionhost
ssh ec2-user@privateSubnetServer
```

What's the best method for handling ssh and users at this point between hosts in the private subnet?

I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

When trying to do it the traditional linux way. I can get to them if I use the AWS created key pairs.

I can't set up or connect to a directory service at this point.

Comment: What do you mean by "handling ssh and users at this point"? Is the above working for you? What are you then doing that gives the `Permission denied` error? Feel free to edit your question to clarify the situation.

Comment: You might want to research ssh `ProxyCommand`, which is a popular way of transiting through a Bastion. For example: [Convenient SSH proxying through a bastion host - William Tsoi - Medium](https://medium.com/@williamtsoi/convenient-ssh-proxying-through-a-bastion-host-cef9eb832100)

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons, either the key is invalid or the proxy command not working as you expecting.

Before that, you set you proxy command like this

```
host bastion
   HostName bastion_Adress
   User centos|whatever
   identityFile /mykeys/ec2.pem
```

Now try to ssh to bastion

```
ssh bastion
```

If the above then bastion working fine, we can set proxy command now.

```
host private_server
  Hostname 10.0.5.45
  user centos
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W %h:%p
```

Now you can ssh to private server

```
ssh private_server
```

Normally these are necessary but just in case of mac happen sometime

```
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

[.ssh/config: "Bad configuration option: UseKeychain" on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455300/ssh-config-bad-configuration-option-usekeychain-on-mac-os-sierra-10-12-6)

You can debug the issue using this flow

- ssh to bastion
- copy your private server ssh key to the bastion
- ssh to private instance

If the above worked it mean bastion **ssh config** is not valid

If the above does not work then the **key** is not valid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Host bastion.ip.address
       User ec2-user
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bastionkey.pem
       CheckHostIP no

Host private.subnet.ip
       User ec2-user
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bastionkey.pem
       ProxyCommand ssh ec2-user@bastion.host.ip -W %h:%p
```