# SSH: Bad configuration option with private key

Tags: git, macos, ssh

I'm trying to setup SSH keys on macOS 10.15 using [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) **and** [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) guide.

The only difference is that I'm setting up ssh inside `~/.config/` instead of `~`

When I try to test the SSH connection to GitHub using `ssh -T git@github.com`, I get the below error:

```
$HOME/.config/ssh/id_rsa: line 1: Bad configuration option: -----begin
......................................................................
...........................PRIVATE KEY................................
......................................................................
$HOME/.config/ssh/id_rsa: line 50: Bad configuration option: -----end
$HOME/.config/ssh/id_rsa: terminating, 50 bad configuration options
```

Below is the SSH `config` file (located at `~/.config/ssh/config`):

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.config/ssh/id_rsa
```

How can I resolve this?

---

Update 1:

I've also tried adding `IgnoreUnknown` value to the ssh config file, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47455373/13055097), but still getting the same error.

Output of `ssh -vT git@github.com`:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data $HOME/.config/ssh/id_rsa
$HOME/.config/ssh/id_rsa: line 1: Bad configuration option: -----begin
......................................................................
...........................PRIVATE KEY................................
......................................................................
$HOME/.config/ssh/id_rsa: line 50: Bad configuration option: -----end
$HOME/.config/ssh/id_rsa: terminating, 50 bad configuration options
```

Comment: Try not putting your keys in `~/.config/ssh`.

Comment: I’m actually trying to make my home directory XDG compliant. Almost everything is going to be in either **~/.config** or **~/.cache**

Comment: But did you try it?