# Git keeps prompting me for a password

Tags: git, github

I've been using Git for a while now, but the constant requests for a password are starting to drive me up the wall.

I'm using Mac OS X and GitHub, and I set up Git and my SSH keys as instructed by GitHub's [Set Up Git page](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/).

I've also added the github SSH key to my Mac OS X keychain, as mentioned on [GitHub's SSH key passphrases page](http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/). My public key is registered with Git.

Nevertheless, every time I try to Git pull, I have to enter my username and password. Is there something other than an SSH key that I need to set up for this?

Comment: Silly question, but have you verified that the SSH key works when simply using ssh to the machine with git?

Comment: You mean something like ssh -T git@github.com ? Yeah, that works just fine (if a little slow).

Comment: See also [Git push requires username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password).

Comment: For https url, you can use (with git1.8.3+) a git credential helper '`netrc`'. See a [full example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309).

Comment: I am a Windows user, and I was also facing password request issue even after adding my public key to authorized_keys file of server. What really the problem was that I was not keeping my public/private keys under .ssh folder of c:\program files\git folder. If anyone is facing such issue, please copy your keys in this folder and try pushing/pulling.

Comment: Set the remote url value in the `.git/config` file of the repository to `git@github.com:{username}/{repo}.git` where you replace with your own username and the repo name, obviously.
The selected answer is flat-out incorrect.

Comment: What helped me: `ssh -Tv git@example.com` (replacing example.com with your GitLab domain) Try to push your changes. If it still doesn't work try this: `git remote rm origin; git remote add origin git@git.<domain>:<username>/<ProjectName>.git; git push -u origin --all; git push -u origin --tags;` If it still doesn't work, try to re add the private key in the website. Last thing to try, add the key from bash: `ssh-add id_rsa`

Comment: You might need to configure your computer with a SSH key and you won't need to constantly submit your password every-time you push the code.

Comment: for people having trouble cloning with an ssh key, make sure you use the ssh clone url as well

Comment: `git config --global credential.helper cache`

Comment: Other possibly related Questions: [Git keeps prompting me for a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-a-password) and [Configuring Git over SSH to login once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh-to-login-once). Cross site: [How to make git not prompt for passphrase for ssh key? (*on superuser*)](https://superuser.com/q/1010542/910769) and [git with ssh keeps asking for passphrase everytime (*on U&L*)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/594529/318461)

Answer (score 937, accepted):

I think you may have the wrong Git repository URL.

Open `.git/config` and find the [remote "origin"] section. Make sure you're using the SSH one:

```
ssh://git@github.com/username/repo.git
```

You can see the SSH URL in the main page of your repository if you click *Clone or download* and choose *ssh*.

And NOT the `https` or `git` one:

```
https://github.com/username/repo.git
git://github.com/username/repo.git
```

You can now validate with *just* the SSH key instead of the username and password.

If Git complains that `'origin' has already been added`, open the `.config` file and edit the `url = "..."` part after `[remote origin]` as `url = ssh://github/username/repo.git`

---

The same goes for other services. Make sure the address looks like: `protocol://something@url`

E.g. `.git/config` for **Azure DevOps:**

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://mystore@dev.azure.com/mystore/myproject/
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: This may be it. When I call git remote -v I get:  
  
origin https://github.com/Foo/Bar.git (fetch)  
origin https://github.com/Foo/Bar.git (push)  
    
whereas to work with SSH it seems that it should be:    
  
origin git@github.com:Foo/Bar.git (fetch)  
origin git@github.com:Foo/Bar.git (push)  
  
This may be because I originally checked out my project using GitHub's Mac application (http://mac.github.com/). Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Either fix the url in the .git/config file, use git-remote to fix it, or delete your local repo and clone it again with the correct URL.

Comment: Just to spell this out (as I needed it): open .git/config and in the `[remote "origin"]` section set `url = ssh://git@github.com/username/Repo.git`. That worked for me.

Comment: Odd, @GregK's solution didn't work for me, but `url = git@github.com:organization/Repo.git` did work. +1 for leading me down the right path though! Success!

Comment: I'm curious why you describe the https url as the "wrong" one, when the git documentation describes it as the recommended method: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys ? Don't get me wrong, I prefer SSH connection myself, but there seems to be a disparity in recommendations.

Comment: I can't stress enough how important it is to CLONE using ssh://git@github/[username]/[reponame].git is you  want to use an key to access GIT not have to type your username and password each time. I found the only way to fix it was to remove the local repo and clone again $ git clone ssh://git@github/[username]/[reponame].git

Comment: @GeneM. I'm pretty sure you can simply change the origin url of your clone in .git/gitrc to avoid re-cloning.

Comment: https URLs work just fine in MacOSX if you use @orkoden's osxkeychain solution

Comment: Editing `.git/config` directly is not recommended when there is a git command for doing the same thing: `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:account/repository`. The reason is you may accidentally corrupt the contents of `.git/config`.

Comment: Just adding that this worked for me, but I did NOT include the `ssh://` prefix to the ssh github url. That is, I simply set the url to `git@github.com:username/repo.git`

Comment: Remote url should be `git@github.com:username/repo.git` - not this nonsense.

Comment: `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
`

Comment: This got me past 1 hurdle, at least git is now using my ssh key, but it still keeps prompting for the public key passphrase on each git operation

Answer (score 663):

### Configuring credential.helper

On OS X (now macOS), run this in *Terminal*:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

It enables Git to use file Keychain.app to store username and password and to retrieve the passphrase to your private SSH key from the keychain.

For Windows use:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

For Linux use:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache // If you want to cache the credentials for some time (default 15 minutes)
```

OR

```
git config --global credential.helper store // if you want to store the credentials for ever (considered unsafe)
```

Note: The first method will cache the credentials in memory, whereas the second will store them in `~/.git-credentials` in plain text format.

Check [here](https://www.tecmint.com/fix-git-user-credentials-for-https/) for more info about Linux method.
Check [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git) for more info about all three.

### Troubleshooting

If the Git credential helper is configured correctly macOS saves the passphrase in the keychain. Sometimes the [connection between SSH and the passphrases stored in the keychain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18458/password-dialog-appears-when-ssh-private-key-permissions-are-set-to-0600/139522#139522) can break. Run `ssh-add -K` or `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to add the key to keychain again.

### macOS v10.12 (Sierra) changes to ssh

For macOS v10.12 (Sierra), `ssh-add -K` needs to be run after every reboot. To avoid this, create `~/.ssh/config` with this content.

```
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

From the `ssh_config` `man` page on 10.12.2:

> **UseKeychain**

> On macOS, specifies whether the system should search for passphrases in the user's keychain when attempting to use a particular key. When the passphrase is provided by the user, this option also specifies whether the passphrase should be stored into the keychain once it has been verified to be correct. The argument must be 'yes' or 'no'. The default is 'no'.

Apple has added [Technote 2449](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2449/_index.html) which explains what happened.

> Prior to macOS Sierra, `ssh` would present a dialog asking for your passphrase and would offer the option to store it into the keychain. This UI was deprecated some time ago and has been removed.

Comment: This is by far the best way to do this since the Github application for OSX (maybe Windows as well) uses the https path for git repos by default. There is also a good reason for using https rather than ssh/git since many corporate networks only allow traffic on port **80** and **443** for security reasons.

Comment: You need git 1.7.10 or newer to use the credential helper.

Comment: +1 for keychain.app solution. This is **GREAT** for me because my employer's git server only supports http served via apache and they strongly discourage using the `.netrc` file method which puts your password in plaintext.

Comment: Note, I got the error `'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command.` as I didn't have the credential helper installed. I followed the instructions here to install it: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#password-caching

Comment: Yes you need to install git with the credential helper. Depending on how you install it (homebrew, macports, source, etc.) you might need to pass some compile flags. For macports, install it with port install git-core +credential_osxkeychain

Comment: For windows use: `git config --global credential.helper wincred`

Comment: Is it still using the git ssh key? I want to make sure I am not bypassing the security and using a less secure the username and password method.

Comment: Yes it is. The password you save in Keychain.app is the one that unlocks the private SSH key on your machine. Your username and password for the git server you use should be different.

Comment: **Error** : git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: Thanks for the Sierra update, I just updated and couldn't figure out why github kept asking for pw when I added the `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain` The config file in my `.ssh` directory fixed me up.

Comment: Mac Sierra 10.2 was the reason this keeps prompting me. `ssh-add -K` doing this fixed the problem and added the missing Identity File back to mac.

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out over the Sierra change. Modifying ~/.ssh/config did the trick!

Comment: Great solution. Though note, you don't even need the `Host *` bit, if you put the rest at the top-level.

Comment: @AndreyLuiz Hey do you know how to do it in linux?

Comment: This answer must be marked as correct one. Came here after installing Sierra, and `ssh-add -K` together with creating `.ssh/config` file did the trick.

Comment: For *Linux* use `git config --global credential.helper cache`

Comment: I have configured `credential.helper` and it worked for a while. But after 3 months the `git fetch` started to ask for credentials again. I looked into keychain and the credentials exist just fine. I entered the same credentials again for the `git fetch` command and new item was created in keychain, with same credentials. Do not know why.

Answer (score 162):

This happened to me when I upgraded to macOS v10.12 (Sierra). Looks like the SSH agent got cleared upon upgrade.

```
$ ssh-add -L
The agent has no identities.
```

Simply running `ssh-add` located my existing identity. I entered the password and was good to go again.

Comment: +1 broken by Sierra upgrade.  Note the password is the password for your SSH key and not your Mac user password.

Comment: Doing ssh-add does work but appears to be reset by closing the Terminal window. Maybe this is a new "feature".

Comment: Heads up - this happened again with another Sierra update (10.12.2) but the same fix applies.

Comment: Does anyone know how to have this not be reset after Terminal is closed?

Comment: Nevermind, found a solution for the issue where this is reset after Terminal is closed: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264974

Comment: got same message but my box broke after updating OSX over last weekend.

Comment: This also worked for me after upgrading macOS Sierra

Comment: I had just updated my macbook pro to 10.12.2 and it broke my git. Using ssh-add totally worked for me. Thanks @amcc!

Comment: this worked after switching from Xfce to KDE for some reason

Answer (score 77):

As others have said, you can install a password cache helper. I mostly just wanted to post the link for other platforms, and not just Mac. I'm running a Linux server and this was helpful: *[Caching your GitHub password in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-linux)*

For Mac:

```
git credential-osxkeychain
```

Windows:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Linux:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
# Set the cache to timeout after 1 hour (setting is in seconds)
```

Comment: I had to scroll down to the third answer to see the Linux instructions, these should be in the primary answer since it is a commonly referenced issue.

Answer (score 74):

Use this:  Replace github.com with the appropriate hostname

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

Comment: I already have that set when viewing `git remote -v`.  Yet, I am still being prompted for password.

Comment: Same, I have set as what he suggested, but I still get prompt for password, how do I prevent that ?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky : Did you ever found a solution for you ?

Comment: This works properly. This is weird that remote URL with `git@**` doesn't prompt credentials and URL with `https@**` does :). Thus I found [this doc](https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password/).

Answer (score 29):

Also look for who is asking you for the passphrase. Is it Git or your SSH agent?

In my case, every time I did `git pull` it was asking me:

`Enter passphrase for key '/work/username/.ssh/id_rsa':`

So I assumed it was Git asking for a passphrase. So I kept hunting for solutions, only to realize later that my SSH agent had shut down. Which can be fixed using `eval $(ssh-agent)`  and `ssh-add` as given [here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/how-to-avoid-being-asked-passphrase-each-time-i-push-to-bitbucket)

Also am pasting below a little snippet you can add to your `~/.bashrc` file (or the equivalent) to ensure that your SSH agent is started on your login.

In any case this was a pretty silly mistake I made, but posting it here, just in case it helps someone save some time from barking up the wrong tree, like I did.

```
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/environment"

# Start the ssh-agent
function start_agent {
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."

    # Spawn ssh-agent
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > ${SSH_ENV}
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 ${SSH_ENV}
    . ${SSH_ENV} > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add
}

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . ${SSH_ENV} > /dev/null
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi
```

Comment: Pretty sure you are missing a line in the code above - as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/18915067/277023 you need to have `SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/environment"`

Answer (score 23):

```
git config credential.helper store
```

Note: While this is convenient, Git will store your credentials in clear text in a local file (.git-credentials) under your project directory (see below for the "home" directory). If you don't like this, delete this file and switch to using the cache option.

If you want Git to resume to asking you for credentials every time it needs to connect to the remote repository, you can run this command:

```
git config --unset credential.helper
```

To store the passwords in .git-credentials in your %HOME% directory as opposed to the project directory: use the --global flag

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Answer (score 12):

In **Windows** for **Git 1.7.9+**, run the following command on the command prompt to open the configuration file in a text editor:

```
git config --global --edit
```

Then in the file, add the following block if not present or edit it accordingly:

```
[credential "https://giturl.com"]
username = <user id>
helper = wincred
```

Save and close the file. You will need to provide the credentials only once after the above change.

Comment: this works perfect, you saved my hours, now I can concentrate on my work, Thanks a lot Brother.

Comment: This did not work for me. "error: There was a problem with the editor '"D:/Programs/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe" fileeditor'"

Answer (score 11):

Use the following command to increase the timeout period so that you could retype password for a while

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 3600'
```

I used it for Bitbucket and GitHub it works for both. The only thing you need to do is
`3600` is in seconds. Increase it to whatever extent you want. I changed it to `259200` which is about 30 days. This way I re-enter my password for every 30 days or so.

Comment: Ok, I've found that this does not persist after a restart, so you still need to enter the password after a restart, regardless of timeout...

Comment: This is a nice way to make in cache :) At least saved my time. Thanks

Comment: @BenWinding because it stores credentials in memory.

Answer (score 10):

Guide to Git on Windows and GitHub using SSH to push/pull: *[An Illustrated Guide to Git on Windows](http://nathanj.github.io/gitguide/tour.html)*

1. Download and install PuTTY
2. Set environment variable 'GIT_SSH' = 'path\to\plink.exe' (in installed putty folder) - **very important**!!!
3. ***Restart Windows Explorer*** for environment variables to take effect (cannot only restart command prompt)
4. Run puttygen.exe to generate new key, copy the *public* key to the GitHub site
5. Save this new *private* key somewhere safe on the disk (preferable not [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29))
6. Run putty.exe and connect SSH to github.co
7. Quickly get to startup folder by running "shell:startup".
8. Make your private key startup with Windows via pageant. Create a shortcut in Startup folder with syntax "path\to\pageant.exe" "path\to\privatekey"
9. We do not need to set the 'puttykeyfile' setting inside .git/config of our repositories
10. **Very important** is that the "SSH clone URL" of GitHub is used and not HTTPS.

Comment: Nobody should be using putty anymore. You can do everything now with built in Windows 10 utilities. Let putty, just be putty.

Answer (score 9):

On Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) this was the only solution that I found to work:

```
eval `ssh-agent`; ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

It was a problem with the ssh-agent not being properly registered in WSL.

Comment: Been a whlie, but this is what fixed my issue.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to [stop Git from always asking](https://www.techiediaries.com/git/stop-git-always-asking-for-username-and-password-when-using-https/) you for the login credentials of your GitHub repository this can be easily done.

### Using SSH instead of HTTPS

You can update the origin remote using SSH instead of HTTPS"

```sh
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/your-repo.git
```

### Configure Git to Store your Password and Username

Here’s how you can make Git store the username and password:

```sh
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Next, save the username and password for a session:

```sh
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

Answer (score 8):

Git will prompt you for a password if you are using the `https` protocol. If you use `ssh`, it will do the authentication [using your private key instead of asking for password](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

Here is how to fix this:

`git remote -v`

This will show the url for origin. And you will notice `https` in this url. ([Example here](https://%20https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop.git))

Now, you will have to just remove this first and add the url with `ssh`

```
git remote remove origin

git remote add origin git@github.com:PrestaShop/PrestaShop.git
```

Comment: After removing and adding the remote repo, if you're unable to push your local branch to GitHub, the below command should help.

```
xpetta@host:~/home/xpetta$ git push
fatal: The current branch ABC-123 has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin ABC-123

```

Answer (score 7):

I feel like the answer provided by static_rtti is hacky in some sense. I don't know if this was available earlier, but Git tools now provide credential storage.

**Cache Mode**

```
$ git config --global credential.helper cache
```

Use the “cache” mode to keep credentials in memory for a certain period of time. None of the passwords are ever stored on disk, and they are purged from the cache after 15 minutes.

**Store Mode**

```
$ git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.my-credentials'
```

Use the “store” mode to save the credentials to a plain-text file on disk, and they never expire.

I personally used the **store mode**. I deleted my repository, cloned it, and then had to enter my credentials once.

Reference: *[7.14 Git Tools - Credential Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)*

Comment: For Windows `credential.helper cache` does NOT work. It should be `git config --global credential.helper wincred`.

Comment: Storing it worked and now it allows me to commit my changes without prompting for a password all the time, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: In Linux this did the job for me `git config --local credential.helper store`. In my case, I'm over HTTPS, in this way I only type username/password one time and after that, my credentials are reused from ~/.git-credentials

Answer (score 6):

If Git prompts you for a username and password every time you try to interact with GitHub, you're probably using the HTTPS clone URL for your repository.

Using an HTTPS remote URL has some advantages: it's easier to set up than SSH, and usually works through strict firewalls and proxies. However, it also prompts you to enter your GitHub credentials every time you pull or push a repository.

You can configure Git to store your password for you. **For Windows**:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Answer (score 5):

I figure you fixed your problem, but I don't see the solution here that helped me, so here it is.

Type in terminal:

```
echo "" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

That will empty your `known_hosts` file, and you'll have to add every host you used and have connected to, but it solved the problem.

Comment: `cat /dev/null > ~/.ssh/known_hosts` will do the same.

Comment: `> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` is even shorter :)

Comment: rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts should do the job too. I would advise against this though.

Comment: If you need to remove a host from ~/.ssh/known_hosts, there is a less impactful way than wiping out the file.  ~/.ssh/known_hosts is just a text file and if you can find the offending hosts in the file, you can just delete their lines.  You may want to back up the file before editing it.  If you only have a few entries in the file, then wiping it out might not be a bad idea.  I work on lots of servers so my ~/.ssh/known_hosts has hundreds of entries in it and I'm not quite ready to delete them all to remove a few entries.

Comment: @papan This does not prevent git from asking me for my password!

Comment: Try that, still prompt for password ... :(

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. MacOS Mojave keychain keeps asking for the passphrase. Your id_rsa should be encrypted with a passphrase for security.
Then try adding it to the keychain `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

If your key is in another folder than ~/.ssh then substitute with the correct folder.

Keychain now knows your ssh key, hopefully, all works now.

If you are still facing the issue then try

```
1. brew install keychain

2. echo '/usr/local/bin/keychain $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa' >> ~/.bash_profile
   echo 'source $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh' ~/.bash_profile

3. ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Hopefully, it should work now.

**Update:** The `-K` flag has since been deprecated. Use the following instead:

```
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 # path to private key
```

Comment: Thank you!  The top solution didn't work for me but using `ssh-add` like you said finally resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Since the "-K" flag is deprecated use "--apple-use-keychain" instead: 
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 4):

Running macOS Cataline 10.15, the keychain caching method was not working for me. And I wanted to use `https://` not `ssh`

Here is what worked for me:

```
git remote rm origin

git remote add origin https://your_git_username:your_git_password@github.com/path_to_your_git.git
```

This should work on GitLab too

Make sure if the username contains an email address, to remove the `@email` part or you'll get an error stating `URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the ONLY solution that worked for me.  your_git_username was critical.  It was actually not necessary to put :your_git_password.  At this point, even though it still asked for a "passphrase", it would now accept the account password.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution to this issue:

`git remote -v`

This will display the URL for origin. If it starts with `https`, we need to remove this URL and replace with URL for `ssh`

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:PrestaShop/PrestaShop.git
```

After you have removed and added the remote repository again, if you're still unable to push your local branch to GitHub, then the command listed below should help to resolve this issue.

```
xpetta@host:~/home/xpetta$ git push
fatal: The current branch ABC-123 has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin ABC-123
```

Alternatively you can open the `.git/config` and find the `[remote "origin"]` section and make sure the URL which is being used doesn't begins with `https` if it begins with `https` replace it with the `ssh` URL from the remote GitHub repo. Same applies to other services listed within `.git/config` such as fetch and likewise, need to be replace with the `ssh` URL.

Answer (score 3):

orkoden's answer on using the keychain with Git in your terminal was incomplete and raises errors. This is what you have to do to save the username and password you enter in the the terminal in your keychain:

```
curl http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain -o git-credential-osxkeychain
sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain
```

Then enter

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

If you have already done the part with Git configuration before the curl stuff, it's no problem; it'll work.

Comment: What if I'm on linux.

Answer (score 3):

As static_rtti said above, change

```
https://github.com/username/repo.git
git://github.com/username/repo.git
```

to

```
ssh://git@github.com/username/repo.git
```

I myself changed the `https` in the .git/config file to `ssh`, but it still wasn't working. Then I saw that you *must* change `github.com` to `git@github.com`. A good way to get the actual correct URL is to go to your project page and click this:

[Change HTTPS to SSH to get the right URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS1ua.png)

Then add this URL to the configuration file.

Comment: I have that in my config config file already what else should I check ?

Comment: Did you change it on github.com as well?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with "codehugger" and using the instruction of "orkoden" it worked for me - on NetBeans 7.3 - when you right-click on the file and select context menu - push - a 'push to remote' window opened - there are two options here:

1. `origin:https://github.com/myaccount/myproject.git/`
2. `https://github.com/myaccount/myproject.git/`

As you can see, the difference is the origin parameter in the URL - you do not want to choose this option (1) you want to check option (2), and that works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are different kind of authentications depending on your configuration. Here are a few:

1. `git credential-osxkeychain`.

   If your credential is invalid, remove it by:

   ```
     git credential-osxkeychain erase
   ```

   or:

   ```
     printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com\n" | git credential-osxkeychain erase
   ```

   So Git won't ask you for the keychain permission again. Then configure it again.

   See: [Updating credentials from the OS X Keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/) at GitHub
2. Your SSH RSA key.

   For this, you need to compare your SSH key with what you've added, check by `ssh-add -L`/`ssh-add -l` if you're using the right identity.
3. Your HTTPS authentication (if you're using `https` instead of `ssh` protocol).

   Use `~/.netrc` (`%HOME%/_netrc` on Windows), to provide your credentials, e.g.

   ```
     machine stash1.mycompany.com
     login myusername
     password mypassword
   ```

Learn more: [Syncing with GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5377703/55075) at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can use your key with GitHub, follow this step in the tutorial, *[Testing your SSH connection](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/)*:

```sh
$ ssh -T git@github.com
# Attempts to ssh to GitHub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows and this has suddenly started happening on out of the blue on GitHub, it's probably due to GitHub's recent [disabling support for deprecated cryptographic algorithms](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/) on 2018-02-22, in which case the solution is simply to download and install the latest version of either the full [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) 
or just the [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases).

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH agent set up, you can also add this to your `~/.gitconfig` to force git to use SSH for all GitHub repos rather than HTTPS:

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = git://github.com/
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

(If you're mostly working with public repos, you can also use `pushInsteadOf` rather than `insteadOf`, as reading from a public repo can be done without authentication).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: check your current configuration

```
cat .git/config
```

You will get:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/path_to_your_git.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[user]
    name = your_username
    email = your_email
[branch "master-staging"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master-staging
```

Step 2: remove your remote origin

```
git remote rm origin
```

Step 3: add remote origin back with your username and password

```
git remote add origin https://your_git_username:your_git_password@github.com/path_to_your_git.git
```

Comment: After you've added the remote origin again you also need to align your branches remote and local - something like this:  

`git branch --set-upstream master origin/master`

Answer (score 0):

### Microsoft Stack solution (Windows and Azure DevOps)

First open the `.git/config` file to make sure the address looks like:

```
protocol://something@url
```

E.g. .git/config for Azure DevOps:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://mystore@dev.azure.com/mystore/myproject/
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

If the problem still persists, open Windows **Credential Manager**, click on the safebox named **Windows Credentials** and remove all the git related credentials.

Now the next time you log into git, it won't go away anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. A repo was requiring me to input credentials every time. All my other repos were not asking for my credentials. They were even set up to track GitLab using HTTPS under the same account credentials, so it was weird that they all worked fine except one.

Comparing the .git/config files, I found that there were 2 key differences in the URLs which was causing the issue:

Does ask for credentials:

```
https://gitlab.com/myaccount/myproject
```

Does not ask for credentials:

```
https://myaccount@gitlab.com/myaccount/myproject.git
```

So adding the "myaccount@" and ".git" resolved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was always getting a password prompt when I tried to **cherrypick** a URL like below:

```
git fetch http://username@gerrit-domainname/repositoryname refs/changes/1/12345/1 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

This URL worked well when cherrypicked on a different machine. However, At my end when I try to cherrypick with *correct password* `abc@12345` I used to get below error:

```
remote: Unauthorized
remote: Authentication failed for http://username@gerrit-domainname
```

In my **git config file** the remote URL was like below:

```
url = ssh://gerrit-domainname:8080/wnc
```

**Solution:**
I resolved the authentication failure issue by providing the **HTTP Password** which I found at
My gerrit account -> Settings -> **HTTP Password**.

The HTTP Password was something like `Th+IsAduMMy+PaSS+WordT+RY+Your+OwNPaSs` which was way different than my actual password `abc@12345`

**Note**: My URL to cherrpick starts with `git fetch ...` So, this solution might work on git checkout/download where the URL starts with `git fetch ...`

Answer (score 0):

Faced same kind of issue.

Please make sure you have properly set the remote origin:

```
$git remote add origin master "https://...git "
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows machine:
Install GitHub CLI

```
choco install gh
```

Then run the command:

```
gh auth login
```

and follow the Instruction

Also you can follow this link:

https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but all answers are a long way around to a simple solution. You want to update your netrc file

nano ~/.netrc
machine github.com login yourusername password ghp_yourtoken