# Server keeps asking for password after i added my key to Bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I've searched quit a bit and found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600652/git-on-bitbucket-always-asked-for-password-even-after-uploading-my-public-ssh) [simular](https://superuser.com/questions/405954/how-can-you-avoid-being-asked-to-enter-your-bitbucket-password-when-you-push-to) topics, but no solution works for me

I have a few repositories on Bitbucket, some private and some in teams. I created a new repository (webroot) with a team (nskiv) as the owner. I added this one local with `git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:nskiv/webroot.git`

I've added some files and pushed these to the repository. Then i connect to my server and when i try to pull i constantly have to enter my password. When i do it works fine, but it's annoying and unnecessary.

The strange part is that i nowhere use the HTTPS link. My local `.git/config` looks like this:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@bitbucket.org:nskiv/webroot.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

On my server i'm logged in with my username (maurice) and copied (`cat /home/maurice/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy`) my key to the team's SSH key settings.

When i try to clone the repo (`git clone git@bitbucket.org:nskiv/webroot.git`) i have to enter my password. But why?

**Edit:**

The solution was to activate the ssh agent with eval `"$(ssh-agent -s)"` One step i forgot configuring my server

Comment: Does your private key have a passphrase? Do you have an SSH agent running? What's the output of `ssh git@bitbucket.org -v`?

Comment: @robert Thank i just recreated my ssh key without passphrase and not i do not have to enter my password anymore!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the answer is that you do not have an SSH agent running. I would go through [these](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) steps and make sure you have an SSH agent running and that you have added your key to it.

Comment: One step i missed during the configuration of my server. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Thanks it was my issue too, I missed to add the key to the ssh-agent: ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa