# Docker clone private repo - Permission denied

Tags: git, ssh, docker

I work with bitbucket repos as a team player. I've got multiple identities on my laptop, say id_rsa and deploy which I generated with

id_rsa:

```
ssh-keygen
```

deploy:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/deploy -C "deploy"
```

and a config file

```
Host bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host deploy
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/deploy
```

In my bitbucket account, I set a SSH key for my account with the `id_rsa` key, and then in my repo I set a SSH key with the `deploy` key.

In command line, when I try to clone my repo as `git clone git@deploy:<team_account_username>/<repo_name>`, I am asked to enter a password the first time, but not after that. Then I tried to clone my repo with Docker :

```
# Use anaconda docker image from ContinuumIO
FROM continuumio/anaconda

# Make ssh dir
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/

# Copy over private key, and set permissions
ADD deploy /root/.ssh/deploy
ADD config /root/.ssh/config
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/*

# Create known_hosts
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# Add bitbuckets key
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# Clone git repos
RUN git clone git@deploy:<team_account_username>/<repo_name>

# Set default directory to execute CMD
WORKDIR /<repo_name>

# Run EART
CMD python app.py
```

and when the script tries to clone the repo, I've got

```
Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpecedly
```

**[EDIT]**

I tried to run those commands directly in the container, and as said in my comment, I am asked for the passphrase when I run the clone command, and that's where my script fails

Comment: What does `docker run --rm <imgname> ls -l /root/.ssh` look like? Can you also include a stripped down app.py that can reproduce the ssh errors?

Comment: ls cannot access /root/.ssh : No such file or directory.... which seems reasonable as my build did not end

Comment: The failure is at the RUN git clone line, it is the clone of the bitbucket repo which fails

Comment: I apparently need more caffeine today, think I understand your workflow now. "I am asked to enter a password the first time" ... that bothers me since the docker build won't be able to enter that password. Makes me wonder if the deploy identity is ever used. The last partial build likely left an image (`docker images -a`) that you can launch with a /bin/sh and debug from there.

Comment: I believe the problem you are facing may be [answered by this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8600652/596285). I suspect this is a git over ssh issue that's unrelated to your docker container.

Comment: It's more likely related to this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391839/clone-private-git-repo-with-dockerfile) so I removed the passphrase of the deploy key and it seems to work

Comment: "passphrase of the deploy key" that was an important missing detail, since as mentioned, docker build can't enter that password.

Comment: The problem might be in passphrase. Try generating key without passphrase. This one should work fine. Also the security might be a concern then.