# Deployment to Digital Ocean from Bitbucket results in error on bitbucket pipeline or password prompt on Digital Ocean

Tags: python-3.x, bitbucket, digital-ocean

I currently have a bitbucket repository with a pipeline to Digital Occean. However, Digital Ocean does not pull from the repo successfully.

So far I have:

- A bitbucket pipeline with pointing to the Digital Ocean droplet
- A bitbucket SSH public key which has been added to the Digital Ocean droplet
- A `deploy.sh` file on Digital Ocean which kicks off the deployment process and is referenced by the pipeline on bitbucket
- A `pull.sh` file on Digital Ocean which retrieves the latest build from bitbucket and starts the application

What I'm finding is that the pipeline on the bitbucket side fails. And, if I attempt to run `pull.sh` manually, I am prompted for the password to the bitbucket repo.

Have I set up SSH incorrectly?

[image]

Note that I can find no syntax errors with the pipeline.

### On Bitbucket

#### Bitbucket Pipeline

Variables `<user>` and `<host>` are correctly configured.

```
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        deployment: staging
        script:
          - cat ./deploy.sh | ssh <user>@<host>
          - echo "Deploy step finished"
```

#### Bitbucket SSH Key

- Private Key is configured
- Public Key is configured
- Known host has been added and a Host Address (the Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet IPv4 address) and has a fingerprint

### On Digital Ocean

#### Authorized Key

- Public key provided by Digital Ocean has been added to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

#### Deploy.sh

Is located in `/`

```
echo "Deploy Script Started"
cd
sh pull.sh
echo "Deploy script finished execution"
```

#### Pull.sh

Is located in '/'

```
cd eg-api
git pull origin master
echo 'Repo: Local Copy Updated'
cd refgator-api
python3 refgator-api.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600652/git-on-bitbucket-always-asked-for-password-even-after-uploading-my-public-ssh).

I had originally cloned the repo with https which meant that I would always be asked for a password.

Changing the git config files to use the SSH url allowed my script to do a git pull without needing a password. Something similar to the below.

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git@bitbucket.org:TheMightyLlama/therepo.git
```

Comment: Make sure to mark this answer as accepted in 48 hours.

Comment: Will do. Cheers.