# Executing 'git pull' from SSH in Dreamhost to GitHub without password

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, dreamhost

I am having difficulty SSH'ing git commands (e.g. git pull) without having to GitHub enter username and passcode.

I can SSH into my Dreamhost server and manually run `git pull`. I then have to enter my GitHub username and passcode. This is fine and dandy but I'd like to run `git pull` **WITHOUT** having to enter my GitHub credentials every time.

Found out that I needed to add SSH keys but the server still asks for GitHub credentials.

I did the following:

1. SSH'd into Dreamhost shared server using PuTTy
2. Did the following:

`$ ssh-keygen -t rsa`

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.

Enter file in which to save the key (/home/funkyserver/.ssh/id_rsa):

Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):   <-- I left this empty

Enter same passphrase again:   <-- I left this empty

Your identification has been saved in /home/funkyserver/.ssh/id_rsa.

Your public key has been saved in /home/funkyserver/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.

The key fingerprint is:

12:c3:12d:88:01:pp:12:b5:ca:33:8g:1q:64:ce:4a:81 funkyserver@wonkyninja  <-- wonkyninja is Dreamhost's server name and this fingerprint is fake

The key's randomart image is:  <-- I left this part out on purpose
```

1. Copied the /.ssh/id_rsa.pub key and added it under the 'Deploy Keys' section @ GitHub.com
2. Back on the Dreamhost server, I SSH'd into the directory with the git repo (e.g. /home/funkyserver/mysite)
3. Ran `git pull` and it still asks me to enter GitHub credentials

What am I doing wrong with the SSH keys? Did I not generate them correctly? Did I not add them to GitHub properly?

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push requires username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password/18348125#18348125) and [Git keeps prompting me for password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-password).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try doing `git remote -v`.

If your remotes are prefixed with `https://` a password will be asked.

You can change over to the `ssh` protocol with `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git`

There is more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github) and on [Github](https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password)

Comment: Brilliant!!! That worked. I changed it from 'https://' to 'git@github.com:username/reponame.git' as you noted above. Now I don't need to enter credentials every time. It said it couldn't verify the GitHub keys but I elected 'yes' anyway and now the Dreamhost server recognizes GitHub.com as a known host.