# Git asks me for password Each and every time I want to commit and push my project

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, bitbucket

I am using Git in Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 8.
Each and every time I want to commit and push my project on bit bucket it asks me for password. How do I save it permanently?

Comment: Related: [Git push requires username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password), [Git keeps prompting me for password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-password). [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the related questions from @Cupcake's comment you could [clone your repo using the SSH URL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git#SetupSSHforGit-Step7.ConfigureyourrepositorytousetheSSHprotocol) and use [SSH keys for authentication](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git#SetupSSHforGit-Step1.ReadaquickoverviewofSSHconcepts). You can then cache the SSH key's password with [Pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

The other option is to use credential helpers as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/19927).