# Github asking for password

Tags: git, version-control, github

This happens when pushing to the remote repo:

[image]

I created a repo in the past and I didn't need to type the password. Why is not apply to all repo?

Comment: This is a repeated question. Kindly refer this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-password?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added  remote with https url syntax:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/zoliky/abctest.git
```

While if you want you ssh key to be used, you should use ssh url syntax:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:zoliky/abctest.git
```

Now to change that, do this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:zoliky/abctest.git
```

Github's explanation is [here](https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using https:// which requires a password not the git:// URL which uses your SSH key.

GitHub actually have a doc about this https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use