# How to automatically authenticate into GitHub from Git Bash using my Public and Private Keys instead of username and password?

Tags: git, authentication, github, public-key, git-bash

Every time when I write

```
git pull origin master
```

or

```
git push origin master
```

or anything else in Git Bash I have to insert my username and password to login into GitHub.

I would like instead to automatically authenticate into GitHub using my Public and Private Keys.

I've already created the keys. They are into my local machine under ~/.ssh. I've attached the public key to my account as well. But I'm always asked for the username and password instead.

What do I still have to do to be able to login direct with the keys?
Many thanks!

Comment: [RT*M](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).

Comment: Already done that. Tests work, but when I try to push or pull it still ask for username and password.

Comment: Are you sure `ssh -T git@github.com` gives you the right response?

Comment: Just tried again and receive the right response: Hi aloysia! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Comment: Are you using the HTTPS URLs for your remotes?

Comment: Thank you for your question. No, it's simple HTTP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git keeps prompting me for a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-a-password)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/15034499 we learn that git won't ask for user and password only if the repository is configured to use ssh and NOT https.

We can change this using:
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/repo.git

Comment: Thank you changing the remote url is what I needed, I had tried everything else from 5 other similar stackoverflow questions as well as the github docs.  I had even worked out that it was the https urls that were giving me grief so I tried this https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/ but still I was asked for username and password each time despite having my username in git config.  

To recap what I needed was:  
 - the username in config,
 - my key fingerprint at github,  
 - the key added to my ssh agent and 
 - the origin url needs to be the git@github one.

Comment: Thank you. The command you provided did not help me but reading that post did, so thanks. Here is the comment that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7773605/9935410