# How to use one password in bash to send it with git pull

Tags: git, bash

**This question about bash scripting.**

I'm not familiar with bash, but I have script that updates all repositories

```
#!/bin/sh
echo UPDATING Client 1
echo ==========================================
cd /var/www/html/client1
git pull
/usr/bin/php symfony goodwin:update
echo Updating SITE
cd /var/www/html/client1/site
git pull
/usr/bin/php symfony goodwin:site-update
echo ------------------------------------------
echo Client 1 UPDATED: `date "+%H:%M:%S  %d-%m-%Y"`
echo ------------------------------------------...
echo UPDATING Client 2
echo ==========================================
cd /var/www/html/client2
git pull
/usr/bin/php symfony goodwin:update
echo ------------------------------------------
echo Client 2 UPDATED: `date "+%H:%M:%S  %d-%m-%Y"`
echo ------------------------------------------
```

So I need to put git password for every git pull command - it is really inconvenient.

**Is there any tricks for bash how to send password only once or set it in command line?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is not the same. I don't need to store password. I need to enter it once while I'm making update keep it in bash scope and use it for pull.

Comment: Why do you feel that bash is the correct answer? The problem is that Git is prompting for a password each time not bash. The only way to stop Git from asking is described in the [duplicated thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-password)