# Not able to avoid password step in git pull

Tags: git, bitbucket, keychain, git-pull

I have my credentials (username/nick (not email) and password) and bitbucket link at keychain but still asks for the password when i use *git pull*. In the link area i have the HTTPS that appears when i do *git pull*. I am using my nickname because everytime i enter my password in terminal i receive this message:

```
A keychain cannot be found to store "nickname"
```

But when i do git pull it asks for the password with that config at keychain.

Now i dont know if i should be using my email instead of my nick, that is also not working in keychain.

I have also did,

```
git help -a | grep credential-
```

and it appears several credentials where i have osxkeychain also, but when i do,

```
git help credential-osxkeychain
```

i get this,

```
No manual entry for git-credential-osxkeychain
```

then if i try to,

```
git credential-osxkeychain set
```

or

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
```

it simply doesnt show anything and i have to do CTRL+C to exit.

Note that when i do,

```
git credential-osxkeychain
```

i get,

```
usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>
```

So what credentials should i use, the nickname instead of email? If not what could be the problem?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

Comment: It seems a pretty obvious that i already pass through that ...

Comment: I'm simply linking to the docs, not saying you didn't read them. might be helpful to those passing by.

Comment: ah ok Kevin sorry, i have saw already that one and a lot more but i have not figure it out

Comment: are you using the ssh bitbucket url? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-password

Comment: no, just https only

Comment: should you be? (not sure, don't use osx. I do use the ssh url.)

Comment: i think i gonna quit from using keychain and use just a plain text in config and then improve privileges and its done. I have saw some examples with ssh url but since i have keychain i was trying to use it instead of ssh url. I have also tried to use other credential.helper with the plain text and it still shows the keychain window with that error lol, i hope when i do the script to handle this it will not stop it from working!

Comment: have you tried to use the SSH link rather than the HTTPs link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a parcial response to the problem but i have found a way to avoid that warning from osxkeychain, was by removing the repo that i have made with git clone under root user and then use another user to create it, after that i have not received that warning anymore.

UPDATE1:

Here is the solution to this:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/sourcetree-throws-credential-osxkeychain-is-not-a-git-command-error-when-pushing-changes-390496445.html