# Git keeps prompting me for passphrase for my SSH Key - Ubuntu VM

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, ssh, bitbucket

I have a repo for my testing site in bitbucket

**SSH**

```
git@bitbucket.org:rkim/rkim-app.git
```

---

My current git config file

**cat .git/config**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:rkim/rkim-app.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[credential]
    helper = store
```

---

**git config --list**

```
user.name=Ryan Kim
user.email=rkim@outlook.com
credential.helper=cache --timeout=3600
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@bitbucket.org:rkim/rkim-app.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
credential.helper=store
```

---

I've tried all the suggestions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-password), and still got prompt to enter my passphrase.

> git pull
>
> Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':

Let me know if anything else I can provide.

Can someone please put an end to this ?

Anythings elses, I should look into ?

Do I need to restart my SSH service or my VM ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Git keeps prompting me for password

```
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

No, it is not password, but passphrase. How did you create that key? What are you trying to achieve?

> I am trying to not enter the passphrase all the time. – ihue 30 secs ago

Then you have two possibilities. Remove the passphrase from the ssh key and you will never have to enter the passphrase again:

```
ssh-keygen -p -P old_passphrase -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Or temporary cache the passphrase somewhere. For this, there is `ssh-agent`, which can be started using

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

and then you can add the key:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You will be prompted once for the passphrase and then never again during your session.

Comment: I am trying to not enter the passphrase all the time.

Comment: @ihue and why it was not written in the question? It does not look like you first question. See the update.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get "Saving key "id_rsa" failed: Permission denied." even though I have full control on the file.

Comment: `ssh-keygen -p -P old_passphrase -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` worked for me only after I copied `id_rsa` to a temporary file, cleared the password on this temp file, then deleted the original file and renamed the temp file to `id_rsa`. Works for me now.