# Atom Github Plugin permanent login request

Tags: git, github, atom-editor, credentials

I use **Atom** as my editor and, since I use **Github**, I **cloned my repo with github desktop** and then **linked Atom to that** with my account's token.

The problem is that every single time I interact with the repo through atom (push, pull, fetch...) **it asks me for my login information**, even if it has my token.

I looked this issue on the internet and on the GitHub repo of Atom but all I found [was this](https://github.com/atom/github/issues/957), which is kinda similar but not the same since my Atom remembers my token but still asks for the username and password:

[image: Picture of the issue]

Is there **any way** in order for Atom **to save my credentials**? It's annoying when pushing or pulling often.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git keeps prompting me for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-password)

Answer (score 1):

There is! Open up your command line and type

```
git config --global --edit
```

Enter

```
 [user]
      name = yourname
      email = yourEmail
      pass = yourPassword
      password = yourPassword
```

and finally save it and restart atom.

Answer (score 1):

Since using your plain-old password is [about to be deprecated](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/), now is a good time to update this answer.

You should instead follow the steps to generate a [secure personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token).

This should work in conjuction with either the UI prompt or the command interface noted above with `git config --global --edit`.

There are some bugs with the prompts/GitHub Identity in Atom that appear to still need working out, so don't be surprised if you have to re-enter this especially after Atom updates for now:

- https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/20445
- https://github.com/atom/github/issues/2558

Hope this clears things up for the foreseeable future.