# Gitlab automate push with personal access token

Tags: git

I need to provide every time I push to gitlab my username and my **personal access token**. This is not about the ssh key, as described in other postings here on stackoverflow.

To copy/pasted the access token every time is very cumbersome.

So is there a save config option to permanently save the access token so that I am automatically authenticated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git keeps prompting me for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-password)

Comment: can you please point me to the place where this post solve the problem for >>personal access tokens <<  which my question is about?

Comment: Using SSH means you don't have to use your access token.

Comment: yes sure, but ssh was NOT the question

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. Just add a store for the credentials in your config with:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

And after you have entered the credentials the next time git will take them from `.git-credentials` instead of asking you. Just a not on security: the store saves everthing in plain text!