# SSH key never use on GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh

I use GitHub to manage my code. And I have already add my public ssh key which generated through `ssh-keygen` command.

However, it needs me to provide username and password when I want to push using `git push` command. And GitHub shows that my SSH key is never used. I don't want to give username and password every time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git keeps prompting me for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-password)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the remote URL:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/repository
```

In this way Git will communicate in the SSH protocol rather than the (possibly) HTTPS protocol, which is the reason you're asked for username and password every time.

I personally have this in my `$HOME/.ssh/config`:

```
Host GitHub github
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
```

And I set the remote URL for my local repositories as

```
git remote set-url origin GitHub:iBug/SomeRepo
```

You can verify you have the correct remote URL set with `git remote get-url origin`:

```
ibug@linux:~/myrepo $ git remote get-url origin
git@github.com:iBug/myrepo
```

If the SSH remote host is correctly configured, try `ssh -T github`:

```
ibug@linux:~ $ ssh -T -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com
Hi iBug! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [add that public key to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).

And you need to check a simple `ssh -T git@github`, ie you see a "Welcome" message.