# How to store Gerrit password?

Tags: git, gerrit

I would like to know how to store the Gerrit Password, because everytime that I need to interact with my remote repository it asks my password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git keeps prompting me for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-password)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+avoid+ask+password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install/configure some "Credential helper" to avoid inputting your credentials repeatedly.

To know more details about that execute:

```
git help credentials
```

Following some credential helper options:

**Ubuntu**

A good credential helper for Ubuntu is the git-credential-libsecret. To install/configure it execute:

```
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev
sudo make -C /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

**Other Unixes**

You can use the [git-credential-cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache). It doesn't need to be installed because it's in the Git package. To configure it execute:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 3600'
```

**Windows**

I think a good option for Windows is the [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/latest).