# Git doesn't save my password on Raspberry Pi

Tags: git, github, raspberry-pi

I have a GitHub repo that I want to push to from my Raspberry Pi using **HTTPS**. The problem is that every time I want to push, git asks me for the username and password. On my regular PC (MacBook Pro) this never happens. Is there some setting to save the password **and not just a workaround that has to be repeated with every repository**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git keeps prompting me for a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-a-password)

Comment: @NilsWerner I am using HTTPS not SSH. I looked it up and the url begins with https:// so everything is right here.

Comment: @user11914177 Look at the dup beyond the accepted answer. There are many hints for https URLs.

Comment: @phd What do you mean?

Comment: @user11914177 Credential helper. [Login:password in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32570160/7976758).

Comment: @phd This is only a workaround. On my PC I never had to do that.

Comment: @user11914177 Because either you use ssh keys, or already set credential helper long ago and forgot about it. There is no magic in git.

Comment: @phd I never logged into git using that and somehow it still is working on my pc!

Comment: @user11914177 I don't believe. I think you simply don't know and don't understand your own configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git#35942890) the credential helper can be used to save the password. It seems it is default on macOS.