# python3 subprocess error capturing output from shell commands

Tags: python-3.x, git

I've followed a number of questions on SO about capturing subprocess output. using git within subprocess seems to output to error instead of stdout or stderr

This is what I want to replicate from shell.

```
git add .
git commit -m 'commit message blah'
git push -u origin master
```

with tracking of output from each stage.
In this example, I have no updates to commit.

```
$git add .
$ git commit -m 'wip'
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

as per code below, I am using

```
output = run("git add .", check=True, capture_output=True, shell=True)
```

and checking output.returncode, but experiencing an CalledProcessError instead of values to output.
any ideas? I can fudge functionality through error trapping, but it's far from optimal.

I can't capture the "nothing to commit, working tree clean" output from 'git push', this seems weird. as are the values for '' stderr & stdout. returncode is a 0 after 'git commit'.

nb: 'git add .' does not produce any output in shell.

environment : ubuntu app on windows 10. Python3, anaconda 64 bit.

```
from subprocess import *
import sys
try:
  print("start git add.")
  #output = run("git add .", check=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
  output = run("git add .", check=True, capture_output=True, shell=True)
  print("git add completed.")
  print("output.stderr:", "'"+output.stderr.decode('utf-8')+"'")
  print("output.stdout:", "'"+output.stdout.decode('utf-8')+"'")
  print("output.stderr==None:", output.stderr==None)
  print("output.stdout==None:", output.stdout==None)
  print("output.returncode:", output.returncode)
  if output.returncode==0:
    output=None
    print("start git commit.")
    #output = run(f"git commit -m 'commit message three'", check=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    output = run("git commit -m 'commit message three'", check=True, capture_output=True, shell=True)
    #exits to exception here when error occurs dueing git commit.
    print("git commit completed.")
    print("output.stderr:", output.stderr.decode('utf-8'))
    print("output.stdout:", output.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
    print("output.stderr==None:", output.stderr==None)
    print("output.stdout==None:", output.stdout==None)
    print("output.returncode:", output.returncode)
    if output.returncode==0:
      output=None
      print("start git push.")
      #output = run("git push -u origin master -f", check=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
      output = run("git push -u origin master -f", capture_output=True)
      print("git push completed.")
      print("output.stderr:", output.stderr)
      print("output.stdout:", output.stdout)
      print("output.stderr==None:", output.stderr==None)
      print("output.stdout==None:", output.stdout==None)
      print("output.returncode:", output.returncode)
      if output.returncode==0:
        print("success @ git push, output.returncode==0.")
except CalledProcessError as error:
  print("CalledProcessError error caught.")
  print('CalledProcessError:An exception occurred: {}'.format(error))
  print("CalledProcessError:sys.exc_info()[0]:", sys.exc_info()[0])
  print("CalledProcessError:output:", output)
  print("CalledProcessError:output.stderr:", output.stderr)
  print("CalledProcessError:output.stdout:", output.stdout)
```

output from this code block

```
start git add.
git add completed.
output.stderr: ''
output.stdout: ''
output.stderr==None: False
output.stdout==None: False
output.returncode: 0
start git commit.
CalledProcessError error caught.
CalledProcessError:An exception occurred: Command 'git commit -m 'commit message three'' returned non-zero exit status 1.
CalledProcessError:sys.exc_info()[0]: <class 'subprocess.CalledProcessError'>
CalledProcessError:output: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in <module>
  File "/home/bmt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'git commit -m 'commit message three'' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 41, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stderr'
```

edit: my main error was using 'check=True' and 'shell=True'
also changing the shell command from one string to a list of strings.

```
output = run("git add .", check=True, capture_output=True, shell=True)
```

to

```
output = run(["git", "add", "."], capture_output=True)
```

Comment: It's not Python. It's *Git* that writes to stderr. Many things you might expect on stdout, actually go to stderr. Not everything goes to stderr, just many things you that you would not expect.

Comment: As a general rule, however, you should not invoke any *interactive* Git command from any program. Git is built out of many tools, many of which are well-suited to be run from other programs. Use those tools, running them in non-interactive ways, to obtain predictable, programmable results. Much of this could be handled better in Git itself general, but `git add` and `git commit` can both be used in non-interactive ways, and you are already doing that part OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some general comments about using Git from other programming languages as comments.  For your more specific case of calling `git commit` here, though, note that your error `CalledProcessError` occurs *because* `git commit` found nothing to commit.  When you did this from the shell:

```
$ git commit -m 'wip'
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

the `git commit` command returned a failure exit status, value 1.  Your *shell* did not complain about this.

When you ran the same thing with:

```py
output = run("git commit -m 'commit message three'", check=True,
    capture_output=True, shell=True)
```

the `git commit` command again returned a failure exit status.  It was *Python*, not Git—specifically, [the `subprocess.run` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)—that raised a `CalledProcessError`, and it did so because you included `check=True`.

This exception jumped out of the normal code flow and went into your `except CalledProcessError` section, where you tried to use the value found via the variable named `output`.  This variable was last bound to a value here:

```py
    output=None
    print("start git commit.")
```

The variable *still* contains `None` at this point, which is why you saw:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 41, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stderr'
```

As a general rule,<sup>1</sup> if you want to capture everything—including the exit code and both stdout and stderr streams—with `subprocess.run`, don't set `check=True`, because that means *jump out of normal processing, raising a CalledProcessError, if the exit code is anything other than zero*.  That is, had you written:

```py
output = run("git commit -m 'commit message three'", capture_output=True,
    shell=True)
```

the whole thing would have behaved more in the way you expected, though you should consult the `output.returncode` value to see if `git commit` succeeded.

Note, too, that `shell=True` is usually a bad idea: it tends to introduce security holes.  [The Python documentation calls this out.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations)  In this case you could use:

```py
output = run(["git", "commit", "-m", "commit message three"], capture_output=True)
```

which avoids the need for `shell=True`.  (The particular example you have here is safe as the entire string is a constant, but this is a bad habit to get into.)

Last, while `git add` and `git commit` can be pretty safely run in such a way as to be non-interactive—you can just inspect their return code value to determine success or failure—`git push` is trickier.  The problem here is that `git push` requires that *your* (local) Git call up some other (remote) Git.  Git will often do this using https/ssl or ssh.  To do *that*, Git invokes other third-party programs, and those sometimes demand input passwords or passphrases.

Because Git can use multiple different third-party programs for this, each of which has its own different options, there is no one right way to avoid it.  See [Git keeps prompting me for a password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7773181/1256452) and [Git push requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6565357/1256452) for various details.

---

<sup>1</sup>Since Python 3.5, however, you can use the error value raised here to access everything:

```
try:
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, check=True)
    ... use result.stdout etc ...
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    ... use err.stdout etc ...
```

but this will often lead to more duplicated code, so it's probably better to just leave out the `check=True` and inspect `result.returncode`.

Comment: thanks. This looks like a reference level answer and deserving of inclusion in the api docs. checking on my implementation atm.