# Git: Installing Git in PATH with GitHub client for Windows

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

How do I install Git in my `PATH` when using the GitHub client for Windows?

I'm running into errors because apparently Git is not installed in PATH. For example, using Atom, trying to install the Linter plugin gives this error:

```
npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
```

Does GitHub for Windows install Git when it installs? (It must, otherwise how does it use Git?) I don't want to double-install it... so how do I just add the Git that's already there to PATH?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

GitHub for Windows does indeed install its own version of Git, but it doesn't add it to the `PATH` variable, which is easy enough to do. Here's instructions on how to do it:

1. **Get the Git URL**

   We need to get the url of the Git `\cmd` directory your computer. Git is located here:

   ```
   C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<guid>\cmd\git.exe
   ```

   So on your computer, replace `<user>` with your user and find out what the `<guid>` is for your computer. (The `guid` may change each time GitHub updates PortableGit, but they're working on a solution to that.)

   Copy it and paste it into a command prompt (right-click > paste to paste in the terminal) to verify that it works. You should see the Git help response that lists common Git commands. If you see `The system cannot find the path specified.` Then the URL isn’t right. Once you have it right, create the link to the directory using this format:

   ```
   ;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<guid>\cmd
   ```

   (Note: `\cmd` at the end, not `\cmd\git.exe` anymore!)

   On my system, it’s this, yours will be different:

   ```
   ;C:\Users\brenton\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_7eaa494e16ae7b397b2422033as45d8ff6ac2010\cmd
   ```
2. **Edit the PATH Variable**

   Navigate to the Environmental Variables Editor ([instructions](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)) and find the `Path` variable in the “System Variables” section. Click `Edit…` and paste the URL of Git to the end of that string. Save! It might be easier to pull this into Notepad to do the edit, just make sure you put *one* semicolon before you paste in the URL. If it doesn't work it’s probably because this path got messed up either with a space in there somewhere (should be no spaces around the semicolon) or a semicolon at the end (semicolons should only separate URLs, no semicolon at beginning or end of string).

If it worked, you should be able to close & reopen a terminal and type `git` and it will give you that same git help file. Then installing the Linter should work. (Atom > File > Settings > Packages > Linter)

Comment: Only adding the `\cmd` folder to your `PATH` should be enough. The `git.exe` in that folder probably links through to the `git.exe` in the `\bin` folder. Adding the `\bin` folder could lead to some conflicts between the executables found in there and other executables found in your path environment.

Comment: @brentonstrine please apply @dennisschagt's suggestion properly.Your answer still describes how to use the `\bin` folder instead of the `\cmd` folder, please fix this.

Comment: Thanks @PetrusKiendys, I just got them switched in my head last time I edited. Should be correct now.

Comment: Thanks!  So that GUID can change?!  That's nasty.  Also hating that it [makes the PATH so long](http://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx).

Comment: Tip: to quickly cut and paste that long honking github path, run the **Git Shell** and type PATH.

Comment: you know, I read the answer, and I still added git.exe to the path :/

Comment: Note that if you run your command line from a folder ( file-> open cmd/powershell), reopening a command line wont be enough. You will have to re-open that folder in order to refresh the environment variables.

Comment: As of Dec 2016 it still exists in this directory which changes after each install which is annoying! One workaround however is to use the DOS truncated reference i.e. `PORTAB~1` in your environment variable PATH and it will resolve. e.g. `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\Portab~1\cmd`. This will work provided no other file/directory in the GitHub folder also starts with `Portab`.

Comment: To expand on Brendan's comment a more generic version would be: ```%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\GitHub\Portab~1\cmd```  This ought to work for everyone (usual caveats aside)

Comment: Environment variables instructions for windows 10 don't work anymore.

Comment: Please mention that they have to change also the USER VARIABLES also. Thats how it fixes.

Answer (score 179):

I would like to add one more thing to what the other answers have said. It is not compulsory that path will be:

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<guid>\bin\git.exe`

In my computer I did not found `Git` there.

BUT git and cmd are located in

**git.exe**

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
```

**cmd**

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

**To add into PATH:**

- Right-Click on My Computer
- Click on Advanced System Settings
- Click on Environment Variables
- Then, under System Variables, look for the path variable and click edit
- Add the path to git’s bin and cmd at the end of the string like this:

  `;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`

**OR**

`;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<guid>\bin;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<guid>\cmd`

To verify, restart cmd and type `git --version` in cmd

Comment: I have it in both places, so what do I do? ignore the long one?

Comment: What I said in reply it worked for me. give it a try it will work.

Comment: If you are using visual studio code or ide with cmd: Don't just close the cmd, restart the entire ide.

Comment: It did work . Thanks for your answer. You specificity is intelligent.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Git\ doesn't exist for me. I'm on Windows 10, GitHub Desktop 2.6.1.

Comment: Are you sure, you did not change the installation location while installing Git?

Comment: Thanks, I had to also reboot my computer for it to take in Unity.

Answer (score 44):

Thanks everyone who have answered.I have seen all answers and to try to make it easy for everyone

**Step 1**: Type **edit environment** and select the option shown

[image]

**Step 2**:
**Select Path and click on edit**

[image]

**Step 3:** In the end add the below statement(you can avoid the first ; if its already there)

```
;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

[image]

**Step 4**:- Click on ok

[image]

**Step 5 **:- One of the important step which is highlighted by one of the users. thanks to him. Please, **CLOSE** command prompt and **REOPEN** then try to write git.

**

- **Close command prompt and restart before trying the below command**

**

Here is the magic

[image]

Comment: So, the freehand scribbling is just meant to highlight that those parts are user-specific, right? Because it's not really hiding anything; it's the same name (with slightly altered formatting) that is affixed to the answer.

Comment: Actually it was for hiding, but i did a bad job over there.

Comment: Your stack overflow's username is the same as that text you scribbled.

Answer (score 22):

I installed `GitHubDesktop` on Windows 10 and `git.exe` is located there:

```
C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-0.7.2\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe
```

Comment: Yeah GHD on Windows 10 64bit, confirmed mine was there as well:
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.0.1\resources\app\git\cmd

Answer (score 14):

GitHub for Windows is now [GitHub desktop](https://desktop.github.com/).

If you have **GitHub for Windows** (before version 1.1), your path should be:

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<guid>\cmd`

If you have **GitHub Desktop** (from version 1.1), your path should be:

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-<version>\resources\app\git\cmd`

After confirming and copying your path, do the following:

- Right click on My Computer or This PC
- Click on Properties
- Click on Advanced system settings
- Click on Environment Variables under the Advanced tab
- Add your path with `;` before it in the variable Path
- Press Ok
- Use a new terminal

Answer (score 12):

Git’s executable is actually located in:
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<guid>\bin\git.exe`

Now that we have located the executable all we have to do is add it to our PATH:

- Right-Click on My Computer
- Click Advanced System Settings
- Click Environment Variables
- Then under System Variables look for the path variable and click edit
- Add the path to git’s bin and cmd at the end of the string like this:

`;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<guid>\bin;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<guid>\cmd`

Answer (score 10):

Add

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32
```

to your PATH variable

Do not create new variable for git but add them as I did one after another separating them by ;

It works for me

Answer (score 5):

Having searched around several posts.  On Windows 10 having downloaded and installed Github for Windows 2.10.2 I found the git.exe in

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin
```

and the git-cmd.exe in

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git
```

**Please note the change to Programs folder within Local from the above posts.**

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work I had to combine many of the above answers, to anyone who this might help here is my much simpler process.

If you have Windows 10 just start typing "edit environmental..." and it'll pop up right away. Click path and Edit… then paste the `;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`
 at the end of the path already there, don't forget the ; to separate your new github path from the current path.

You do not need the guid but if you want to know how to find it open bash, type `git --man-path`

Answer (score 2):

## Updated for the Github Desktop

Search up "Edit the system environment variables" on windows search

- > Click *environmental variable* on the bottom right corner
- > Find *path* under system variables and click edit on it
- > Click *new* to add a new path
- > add this path: C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin\github.exe

To make sure everything is working fine, open cmd, and type github.exe

Answer (score 1):

If you use SmartGit on Windows, the executable might be here:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\bin\git.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vscode's terminal then it might not work even if you do the environment variable thing, test by typing 
`git`

Restart vscode, it should work.

Comment: Having added git to my system path and seeing no effect, this was indeed what sorted this for me. Nice shout!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 2.6.6 version

git Path:
C:\Users<USER>\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.6.6\resources\app\git\mingw64\bin

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install it on `PATH`. You need to make sure the `command` is able to find Git, that I presume is already installed. Ensure the CLI you execute is on the `PATH`. If you use CMD, you can use something like:

```sh
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<guid>\cmd\
```

Now, when you open your terminal again from which you execute `npm` (I presume you're not executing it from an IDE, because in that case the PATH has to be set to the process launching the IDE or within the IDE itself), and run the `npm` command of your choice, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `git.exe` and `git-lfs.exe` files were in a different folder (`C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\`). I showed the new related paths in unity and pushed the button Find System Git. and it worked.

Related picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this one works fine on Windows

> ;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd

It's very important to restart your PC after modifying the Environment PATH to see the effect.

Answer (score -1):

To fix a problem, in my case: I checked Git folder under c:\program files\Git. I didn't find git.exe, so delete the Git folder and install it again. Declare them in the environment variables as shown above. the problem will be solved.

Comment: That's a bit harsh. Probably not the best solution.