# Cannot find command 'git' - windows

Tags: django, pip, django-mongodb-engine

I am trying to install mongodb_engine with my python django application, however I am getting this error

```
Cannot find command 'git'
```

I am trying this command from mongodb documentation. http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5
```

I believe git here is causing the problem since the project is stored in git repo. Is there a way to install git to run this pip command? I tried multiple sources but wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Were you able to resolve it? Did you install 'git' ? Where did you install it from? Can you please tell me the whole thing you did. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Download and Install git in your windows from here:

https://git-scm.com/download/win

Then add its installation bin path to your windows's environment path. Then you will find the git command at the command prompt globally.

This may solve you problem.

How to change environment variables : [Git: Installing Git in PATH with GitHub client for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/git-installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows)

For Visual studio code restart after adding the environment variables

Comment: Where to install the git from? I see a lot of git program online. I am not sure which one to install. Can you please tell me?

Answer (score 51):

If your using Anacoda, then you can try this

```
conda install git
```

Comment: You're correct!

Comment: You'll also need to add the installed directory to your PATH. In my case, that was $User\Anaconda3\Library\bin\

Answer (score 2):

Add the path of git.exe to your windows environment variable called 'path'.
 My git.exe is in the path of 'C:\Users\LW\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin\git.exe'. Your can find your exe file in the similar folder path.

Answer (score 0):

You can install git and configure the path with the git directory in System variables path.

Comment: is it different to the highest rated accepted answer to this question?

Comment: It's more like a comment then an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide answers according to [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)