# Installing Git Repository using pip

Tags: git, github, pip

I am trying to install the following git repo. But it says cannot find command 'git' though I have git software installed in my computer.

`pip install git+https://github.com/NREL/ditto.git@master`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find command 'git' - windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565779/cannot-find-command-git-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put the path?

If you have **GitHub for Windows** (before version 1.1), your path should be:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_\cmd

*After confirming and copying your path, do the following:*

- -Right click on My Computer or This PC
- -Click on Properties
- -Click on Advanced system settings
- -Click on Environment Variables under the Advanced tab
- -Add your path with ; before it in the variable Path
- -Press Ok
- -Use a new terminal

Comment: My one is the latest verison of github. I just downloaded and installed it, 2.17 I guess. Should the path still be the same? And where should I add this path? 
File >> Local repository? Or File >> New repository?

Comment: your path should be something like this    C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\

Comment: I have been able to add the path to the path variables, and checked it with `git --version`. But while pip installing the code from the original post, it is showing the following error 
`Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\mrahman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-j_5r5727-build
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\mrahman\pip\pip.log`

Comment: maybe your pip command isnt upgrade try                                                 
 -->  python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  --> pip install "package-name" if you are up to date and you still have problem try sudo ---> pip3 install git+https://github.com/donnemartin/gitsome.git
Solve my issue (I have both python versions installed).

Answer (score -1):

Please add
[Git Installed Directory]/usr/bin and
[Git Installed Directory]/bin

to your PATH environment variable in Windows 10.

Comment: This simply repeats the accepted answer.