# Python: Pandas support in Pint

Tags: python, pandas, pint

I am trying to reproduce the example described in the Python Pint library [here](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pint-pandas.html).

In the section "Reading from csv" when running the following line:

```
df_ = df.pint.quantify(level=-1)
```

I got the following message error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pint'

Has anybody a solution to that?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards.

Comment: did you `import pint` ?

Comment: I was reading, it seems like pint-pandas comes in a different github branch than "normal" pint

Comment: yes I imported pint. I exactly reproduced the example described there. I guess there is something missing. Something more to import? But I could not find what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ivan noted in the comments, you need to install `pint-pandas` package:

`pip install git+https://github.com/hgrecco/pint-pandas.git`

[Pandas has an open issue](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/issues/1001#issuecomment-579210723) regarding this.

Comment: Thank you, it works like this! To be complete, one also needs to [install git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565779/cannot-find-command-git-windows) before running the pip install command.