# Adding Git to PATH Variable - Can't find GitHub under AppData/Local

Tags: windows, git, command-line, installation, path-variables

I was following this guide here on how to add `Git` to my Path variable so I can use it from the command line (Not just Git Bash).

[Installing Git in PATH with GitHub client for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows)

To quote an answer, Git was supposedly located here

> Get the Git URL
>
> We need to get the url of the Git \cmd directory your computer. Git is
>   located here:
>
> C:\Users\\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_\bin\git.exe

I opened File Explorer and went to the directory `C:\Users\AppData\Local\`

Under the view tab, I have `Hidden Items` checked. I cannot see a GitHub folder listed. In the search bar, I appended GitHub to the end of the directory path and got the following message

```
Windows can't find 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\GitHub'. Check the spelling and try again.
```

I'm trying to add Git to my environment path variable, but can't find where git is located.

In Git Bash, I was able to try `which git` where I got `/bin/git`

But I'm not sure how I can find what to put in under environment variable.

Doing a random search, I actually found that the Git folder was located here

```
C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Git
```

But what am I supposed to enter for the path variable? This is different from the answer in the other question.

Answer (score 16):

Just add the path to the command. This was the path to add to the end of the windows PATH.

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\
```

Now we should be able to find `git.exe` by typing

```
git
```

Comment: The path for me on win10 was: C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin

Answer (score 7):

It turns out Git was being sneaky!

It was supposed to be installed in `AppData/Local`, but was actually installed in the `Program Files(x86)` directory.

I added this to my Path variable after a semicolon

```
C:\Windows\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin\git.exe
```

And magically, I can run git again.

Comment: I'm glad that this worked for you, but you should be aware that you've (probably) found a separate Git installation. Git and GitHub are separate and largely unrelated. GitHub for Windows ships its own embedded version of Git, and the one in `Program Files (x86)` is almost certainly from something else (possibly [msysgit](https://msysgit.github.io/)).

Comment: Have you also installed [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/)? It's certainly not required, but the guide you were following was for that product, not for Git from git-scm.com.

Comment: You mean you added that in to the Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables and then edited the Path and put it behind the line with a ; before it?

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 7 using GIT 2.7.2 I used this in the path under environment variables:

`;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\cmd`.  I then typed git --version from a command prompt and got:

```
git version 2.7.2.windows.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is found in this place https://stackoverflow.com/a/34767523/5842689

the best thing is you can test if work in cmd.

"o verify, restart cmd and type git --version in cmd"

it works for me cause the real path in my case (Win10 x64)is 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe