# BitBucket and PowerShell

Tags: bitbucket

I am very new to BitBucket.Problem is that PowerShell does not recognize git command.What I am trying to do is to Clone.When i copy address to PowerShell and press **Return** this message shows:

The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spellin
g of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ git <<<<  clone https://B@bitbucket.org/B/firstrepository.git
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message has the answer. Your git application seems not to have been added to system environment path variable. Please refer to this thread -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows -- for installing and adding GIT to PATH variable.

Comment: But I do not have installed GitHub on my PC, i am using BitBucket web service

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show the exact commands you provided in your powershell command-line ?

Comment: C:\Users\LAZAR\repos> git clone https://LazarB@bitbucket.org/LazarB/firstrepository.git

The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spellin
g of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ git <<<<  clone https://LazarB@bitbucket.org/LazarB/firstrepository.git
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: First I login to BitBucket then I make repository.After that i click Clone and and copy the address "git clone LazarB@bitbucket.org/LazarB/firstrepository.git" to PowerShell. and after pressing enter the error shows

Comment: C:\Users\LAZAR\repos> git clone LazarB@bitbucket.org/LazarB/firstrepository.git

The first term "git" in your command is the application name. In order to use that application you have to install it. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows  or https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git for installing and you should not see that error message again if correctly installed.

Comment: This is it,thanks @bigyanshr !!!

Answer (score 0):

For posterity purposes I'm going to break out the hidden comment above by @bigyanshr into an answer:

Be sure to install the Git application as described on either [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows) or [the Git 'Getting Started Installing Git' guide](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git). This includes updating your PATH variable to include to your new Git installs 'Git/cmd' folder.