# I am very new to Node,js and "npm install" is throwing a lot of errors

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, npm-install

I am trying to use https://github.com/avatarkava/beavisbot-dubtrack-fm/tree/f302f4a278ca308027c05f52c3c0dd30f72a2e60. As i read in the read me i ran `NPM install` In the root folder using Windows PowerShell, and it came back with these errors:

```
PS C:\Users\Ryan> cd desktop
PS C:\Users\Ryan\desktop> cd plug
PS C:\Users\Ryan\desktop\plug> npm install
npm WARN package.json BeavisBot@2.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:63:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:72:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git://github.com/jpravetz/node-datatable.git resetting remote C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jpravetz-node-datatable-git-1942cdb7 because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:63:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:72:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git://github.com/AvatarKava/cleverbot-node.git resetting remote C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-AvatarKava-cleverbot-node-git-2c5ade26 because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:63:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:72:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git://github.com/plugCubed/plugAPI.git resetting remote C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-plugCubed-plugAPI-git-570cfe8a because of error: { [Error: not found: git] code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/plugCubed/plugAPI.git C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-plugCubed-plugAPI-git-570cfe8a: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/plugCubed/plugAPI.git C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-plugCubed-plugAPI-git-570cfe8a: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/jpravetz/node-datatable.git C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jpravetz-node-datatable-git-1942cdb7: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/jpravetz/node-datatable.git C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jpravetz-node-datatable-git-1942cdb7: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/AvatarKava/cleverbot-node.git C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-AvatarKava-cleverbot-node-git-2c5ade26: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/AvatarKava/cleverbot-node.git C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-AvatarKava-cleverbot-node-git-2c5ade26: undefined
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.20
npm ERR! code ENOGIT

npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ryan\desktop\plug\npm-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Ryan\desktop\plug>
```

I have tried running `npm install` a few times to see if it was a one time error, but I get the same thing each time.

On a side note, if this is easier to run on a different OS instead a virtual machine let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you that you don't have `git` installed and located on your path. npm wants to call `git`, so you will need to install it and put it on your PATH to resolve this issue:

https://git-scm.com/download/win

UPDATE:

You can modify your PATH by going to the start menu and searching for "path", then "Edit environment variables for your account". The path to add should be the git install path, most likely C:\Program Files\Git\bin;

If your path is different, try looking it up in the directory explorer.

Comment: I installed git, but i can't figure out how to change the path.  I have attempted to use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26620861/5853128, i was able to follow the path all the way to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<guid>\ `, but the `cmd\git.exe ` was no where to be found

Comment: Note that you need to restart PowerShell to make environment changes become effective. You can also modify the `PATH` variable in the process environment (`$env:PATH += ';C:\Program Files\Git\bin'`), but that modification is volatile and will vanish when you close the PowerShell console window.

Comment: Perfect @pholtz that worked! Now i just have to go download the python interpreter then it should work! unless this means something different then the interpreter `(Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.)`