# How to Run Git commands on Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: git, netbeans

I want to run some git commands locally to clean up some stuffs. I am on Windows and i am unable to use the netbeans terminal. Git command is not recognized. So my question is i there is a way to run

```
   git rm *.exe
```

or some other commands. I don't want to use GUI of Netbeans here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; unzip the archive [PortableGit-2.7.4-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.7.4.windows.1/PortableGit-2.7.4-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, [add its folder (`/bin`) to your `%PATH%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34767523/6309), and git will be recognized.

Go to the root folder of your git repo, and do a git status to check that git is working.