# Command prompt error

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap

Hi  I'm trying to install bootstrap-saas with bower via CMD into a speciffic folder.
I've  allready installed the latest version of nodejs with Global NPM

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\acasa>cd ..

C:\Users>cd ..

C:\>cd proiecte

C:\proiecte>cd primul

C:\proiecte\primul>npm install -g bower
C:\Users\acasa\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower -> C:\Users\acasa\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\bower\bin\bower
C:\Users\acasa\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- bower@1.8.0


C:\proiecte\primul>bower install bootstrap-saas --save
bower ENOTFOUND     Package bootstrap-saas not found

C:\proiecte\primul>bower install fontawesome
bower ENOGIT        git is not installed or not in the PATH

C:\proiecte\primul>
```

And I get the same error over and over and over again. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first error, it's bootstrap-sass, not saas. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

For the second error, you should (as the prompt indicates) install git: https://git-scm.com/. If you already have installed git, there's already guides on how to set the path variable, like: [Installing Git in PATH with GitHub client for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows)

Comment: OK , for the first error is my bad. But afther installing git i get the same error message . What should I try next?

Comment: Did you check out the last link I've included? That should solve the second problem