# Python script throws WindowsError in the Windows command line, works in Git Bash

Tags: python, git, bash, cmd, path

I'm currently building the source code for Adblock Plus for a school 
project and I'm using the Autoinstall addon to easily deploy to my 
browser, however the provided build tools in Python only seem to work 
when I execute them in the Git Bash for some reason.

Here is the error message when I try to execute the command in the 
Windows command line:

```
C:\Users\Evert\Documents\GitHub\adblockplus>python build.py autoinstall 8888
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Evert\Documents\GitHub\adblockplus\ensure_dependencies.py", line 380, in <module>
    resolve_deps(repo)
    File "C:\Users\Evert\Documents\GitHub\adblockplus\ensure_dependencies.py", line 324, in resolve_deps
    update_repo(target, vcs, rev)
    File "C:\Users\Evert\Documents\GitHub\adblockplus\ensure_dependencies.py", line 272, in update_repo
    resolved_revision = repo_types[type].get_revision_id(target, revision)
    File "C:\Users\Evert\Documents\GitHub\adblockplus\ensure_dependencies.py", line 106, in get_revision_id
    return subprocess.check_output(command, cwd=repo).strip()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Command '['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Evert\\Documents\\GitHub\\adblockplus\\ensure_dependencies.py', 'C:\\Users\\Evert\\Documents\\GitHub\\adblockplus']' returned non-zero exit status 1
Failed to ensure dependencies being up-to-date!
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "build.py", line 18, in <module>
    buildtools.build.processArgs(BASE_DIR, sys.argv)
    File "C:\Users\Evert\Documents\GitHub\adblockplus\buildtools\build.py", line 601, in processArgs
    commands[command](baseDir, scriptName, opts, args, type)
    File "C:\Users\Evert\Documents\GitHub\adblockplus\buildtools\build.py", line 55, in __call__
    return self._handler(baseDir, scriptName, opts, args, type)
    File "C:\Users\Evert\Documents\GitHub\adblockplus\buildtools\build.py", line 225, in runAutoInstall
    packager.autoInstall(baseDir, type, host, port, multicompartment=multicompartment)
    File "C:\Users\Evert\Documents\GitHub\adblockplus\buildtools\packagerGecko.py", line 334, in autoInstall
    createBuild(baseDir, type=type, outFile=fileBuffer, multicompartment=multicompartment)
    File "C:\Users\Evert\Documents\GitHub\adblockplus\buildtools\packagerGecko.py", line 294, in createBuild
    version = getBuildVersion(baseDir, metadata, releaseBuild, buildNum)
    File "C:\Users\Evert\Documents\GitHub\adblockplus\buildtools\packager.py", line 58, in getBuildVersion
    buildNum = getBuildNum(baseDir)
    File "C:\Users\Evert\Documents\GitHub\adblockplus\buildtools\packager.py", line 46, in getBuildNum
    result = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-list', 'HEAD'], cwd=baseDir)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This isn't a huge problem for me since it does build, but I can't help but 
wonder: what is the difference between these two environments that makes 
this script work?

Comment: My first guess is that it is trying t oexecute something (the subprocess modulve is a hint) and that is not available under windows in that path. Example /c/windows/notepad.exe vs c:\windows\notepad.exe.

Comment: the problem is probably in "subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-list', 'HEAD'], cwd=baseDir)" - check if git is in system path etc. I'd help you more, but windows is black magic to me.

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about what to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that `git.exe` isn't in your Windows `PATH`, which it definitely is in Git Bash :) .  You have two "not found" errors, both for `git`:

1. In `ensure_dependencies.py`, line 106, executing `command`.  Per [the source](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockplus/blob/master/ensure_dependencies.py#L105), the command is `['git', 'rev-parse', '--revs-only', rev + '^{commit}']`.
2. In `packager.py`, line 46, executing `['git', 'rev-list', 'HEAD']`.

Both of those are a missing `git`.  To fix, before running `python build.py`, do

```
path %PATH%;c:\<wherever git.exe is located>
```

or add the location of `git.exe` to your system PATH using the Control Panel.

**Edit** If your Git installation is from GitHub, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26620861/2877364) gives details about adding Git to your `PATH`.

Comment: Thank you, adding git.exe to my path was the solution.