# installing gulp on windows 10 with local server on XAMPP and laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, gulp, windows-10-desktop

I am trying to install `gulp` in the development environment on `XAMPP` in the root of the `test site`. No matter what I do I get the following error, I cannot figure out what is wrong:

```
# npm install
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:jeroennoten/webpack-stream.git C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jeroennoten-webpack-stream-git-patch-1-b24e730a: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:jeroennoten/webpack-stream.git C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-jeroennoten-webpack-stream-git-patch-1-b24e730a: undefined
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOGIT

npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\Users\Username\Documents\Xampp\htdocs\development.test\npm-debug.log
```

I have tried to use an older version of `nodejs` just to see if this could help to solve the problem, but did not get anywhere with it either.

I am on Windows 10 64bit with XAMPP local server and with gulp installed globally on my machine.

Please help!!!

Comment: Read the error message, it says you don't have have `git` installed, or it's not in the path for `npm` to find.

Comment: I am a newbie, so I do not really know what I should do and where I have to add that git to make it work. Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

So just to answer my own question and possibly help others, whom are also experiencing the same problem as I was, I have found an answer on the Stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows)

Just be sure to install GitHub on your computer prior to following the step-by-step instruction given in the answer there.

Thanks to kind people, who can actually take there valuable time and post a proper answers instead of downgrading the question almost immediately and without even trying to help others.