# React-Native app installation error

Tags: react-native

I want to install simple react native app

I have write following commands

```
npm i -g create-react-native-app

npm create-react-native-app my-project
```

but it showing following error[image]

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install git.

See instructions for installing git on Windows from here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: i installed it then also it showing me same error.

Comment: add git to your path variable

Comment: how i can do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows