# Git Cli not find on your path Ionic framework issue

Tags: git, cordova, ionic-framework

I started to learn ionic framework to make apps. I prefer this [tutorial](https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/)

I installed everything as per the tutorial, but after that, when hitting `ionic start myApp tabs` in command line, it gives an error:

```
Git cli not found on your path
```

I also installed git. But it still gives an error.

[image]

Comment: You have to add git to your path environment variable

Comment: @devqon How to do it?

Comment: please don't add the image like that, just add the error logs as text, that is more than enough.

Comment: @SagarKodte https://stackoverflow.com/a/34767523/3153169

Comment: One of the worst framework I've ever seen in my life. Its installation process is like fighting in the world war ||. Bull shit ionic framework. First install this, then this, then this, then this, and finally when set it up via cmd a lot of errors are displayed i-e git hub, port, server, cordiva and proxy errors. Just f*** it out. It waste your stamina of app development in the installation process. Ionic framework is the worst framework ever. Deleted it

Answer (score 0):

You have to add git.exe path to your system path.

For me it is C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Git program folder is not ok. ex; C:\Program Files\Git

Close current CMD and Start again.