# npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH

Tags: windows, git, npm, path, zenbot

I can't seem to get zenbot to install I am new to node.js, so please be kind. I am getting all kinds of error I do have git installed. I followed the install instructions and I really don't know where to start. I am a Java and C programming trying to cut my teeth on something new and learn through the bumps and bruises.

```
C:\zenbot>npm install
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-25T08_17_27_513Z-debug.log

----- Log file--
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.9.3
4 verbose npm-session 5167d752483581f2
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall zenbot4@4.0.5
7 info lifecycle zenbot4@4.0.5~preinstall: zenbot4@4.0.5
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
12 silly install loadShrinkwrap
13 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for forex.analytics@github:mkmarek/forex.analytics#7bc278987700d4204e959af17de61495941d1a14 No git binary found in $PATH
14 verbose stack Error: No git binary found in $PATH
14 verbose stack     at checkGit (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\util\git.js:199:17)
14 verbose stack     at spawnGit (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\util\git.js:178:10)
14 verbose stack     at pinflight (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\util\git.js:110:12)
14 verbose stack     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js:29:24
14 verbose stack     at Promise._execute (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:300:9)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:483:18)
14 verbose stack     at new Promise (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:79:10)
14 verbose stack     at _inflight (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js:28:25)
14 verbose stack     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\promise-inflight\inflight.js:22:14
14 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:606:10)
14 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
14 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
14 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
15 verbose cwd C:\zenbot
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
17 verbose argv "C:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
18 verbose node v8.9.3
19 verbose npm  v5.5.1
20 error code ENOGIT
21 error No git binary found in $PATH
22 error Failed using git.
22 error Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
23 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

---

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>git -v Unknown option: -v usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value] [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path] [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare] [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>] <command> [<args>] –
```

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>git -v
Unknown option: -v
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Git in PATH with GitHub client for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying within `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, probably `git` executable is available over there.

Change the directory to `C:\` and then try `git --version`.

If you get error `git` is not recognized..., then `git` path is not set in environment variables.

So, open your environment variable settings and set the git executable path to `PATH` variable.

Comment: Running 'path' will show the current contents of your system's PATH variable.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's missing from the alpine image.
npm install is kinda fundamental to node and git is required to install certain dependencies.

Including

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache git
```

in the dockerfile will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

While running RUN npm install --progress=false --unsafe-perm in docker file on jenkins

FROM node:10.15.0-alpine (as the base image)

I was getting npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH

Solution- added below line in docker file and it worked

**RUN apk update && apk upgrade && 

apk add --no-cache git**