# Laravel Error Running Artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel so you may have to bear with me, but I seem to be having a small issue. Now first of all I've created a basic template and managed to get it to run using phpMyAdmin with Wamp and it worked fine. I've also been given an old project that I've been asked to take a look at but for some reason I can't get it to run.

So this is the process I'm using:

1: Opened cmd change to the correct directory

2: Install the composer

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

3: Change directory to the project directory

4: Run `php artisan key:generate`

ERROR:

> PHP Warning: 
>   require(C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 54
>
> Warning:
>   require(C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 54 PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 54
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 54
>
> C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject>php artisan
>   migrate PHP Warning: 
>   require(C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 54
>
> Warning:
>   require(C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 54 PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 54
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\wamp64\www\pmanager\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 54

Updated error after installing Git

> Warning:
>   require(C:\wamp64\www\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 54
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp64\www\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\wamp64\www\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 54 PHP Warning: 
>   require(C:\wamp64\www\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 54 PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp64\www\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\wamp64\www\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 54 Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the
>   pre-update-cmd event returned with error code 255

Composer Install Command Output:

> Loading composer repositories with package information Installing
>   dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file Warning: The lock
>   file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You
>   may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
>   Package operations: 51 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
>     - Installing golonka/bbcodeparser (v2.1.0): Downloading (failed)    Failed to download golonka/bbcodeparser from dist: The
>   "https://api.github.com/repos/golonka/BBCodeParser/zipball/d597b1c0a6472ff7003776dd5c74e084270da041"
>   file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
>       Now trying to download from source
>     - Installing golonka/bbcodeparser (v2.1.0): Cloning d597b1c0a6
>
> [RuntimeException]   Failed to clone
>   https://github.com/golonka/BBCodeParser.git, git was not found, check
>   that it is installed and in your PATH env.
>
> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts]
>   [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] []...

Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "illuminate/html": "^5.0",
        "golonka/bbcodeparser": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "myproject\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: did you run 'composer install' command?

Comment: first run `composer` command and see if it spits out the help file. If so you know composer is installed correctly. Next run the command `composer install` and it will create the vendor folder and import everything your missing.

Comment: The `composer` command worked fine but when I ran the `composer install` I got an error which I've now added to the post.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install git`

Comment: `sudo` is not recognized

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed your on windows. Download it from here https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: Just installed it, now where do we go from here

Comment: run `composer install` again

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: run `git` command, it should spit out the help file. if not you need to add it to your PATH env

Comment: It says git is not recognized

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows

Comment: open git bash and go to ur project folder and try composer install

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167283/room-for-rob-biermann-and-matt-hutch

Comment: can i see your composer.json file ? and what's the OS you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your errors there are two reason this could happen.

**No git installed**

> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

to resolve this install git and see whether git commands working on the console

**You have added deleted packages**

> Failed to clone https://github.com/golonka/BBCodeParser.git, git was
>   not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.

see whether there's a package called `golonka/bbcodeparser` in our composer.json and delete it

after resolving these two run `composer install` in your project folder see whether its working or not. after that you can run `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering. I've added a copy of my composer.json to the post finished installing Git. I then tried removing the `golonka/bbcodeparser` that appears on line 10 and then tried the `composer install` commarnd and got "composer.json" does not contain valid JSON"

Comment: @MattHutch remove composer.lock file and run composer clear-cache then run it again, your composer.json file is fine, i checked it and there are no any erros

Comment: Still no joy, it's still outputting the error in the post.

Comment: I've added a updated output error to the post so you can see it.

Comment: @MattHutch this one : [RuntimeException] Failed to clone https://github.com/golonka/BBCodeParser.git, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env. ??

Comment: When I run the `git.exe` command in a fresh cmd it outputs the user help, doesn't that mean it's installed

Comment: @MattHutch yes, im asking whats the error you getting, there are few errors in your post

Comment: I get this when I run `composer install` or `composer update`

Comment: @MattHutch can you type just `composer ` and see if you get any errors

Comment: @MattHutch well that's weird, you could get that error if you run `php artisan key:generate` without composer update, i believe this is your project folder C:\wamp64\www\websiteprojectNew\websiteproject right ? so when you run `composer update` composer never need to require your project vendor file. so delete  vendor in your project folder and the lock file an try it again, you are not using composer.phar  right ?