# Error While running the project in vs code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm new to react native. I'm trying to run the project i'm running the cmd 'npm install' But it is showing error.

```
D:\vox-android>npm install
npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/tradle/react-native-http.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\kisuser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-19T09_22_40_673Z-debug.log
```

Comment: do you have git installed?

Comment: no, but i'm installing i have to give the path first to git

Comment: just default install git, then im assuming that you have node.js installed, just follow this tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Comment: But the problem is that in environment variable the node path is present if i'm deleting that it show error for node

Comment: yes, i have node installed

Comment: on your environment variables you should have your git path and nodejs, like this: 'C:\Program Files\nodejs' and 'C\Program Files\git\cmd' not sure about the git one, but thats what  I have here

Comment: Both path have to merge is this you are saying?

Comment: im just saying that you should have node and git on your environment variables

Comment: i made the diffrent for both But i'm getting again the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Git in PATH with GitHub client for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows)

Comment: i manually created the git folder then i set gitpath in variable environment. like this ;C:\Program Files\Git

Comment: But i'm still getting the same issue