# Cannot find module ‘expo/tools/LogReporter’

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I try to run my first react-native app with expo start and below error occur
Cannot find module ‘expo/tools/LogReporter’

I find several questions about this problem and follow but none of them can’t solve my problem (I checked all of them serveral times and did works that they said)

Package.json :

```
{
“main”: “node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js”,
“scripts”: {
“start”: “expo start”,
“android”: “expo start --android”,
“ios”: “expo start --ios”,
“eject”: “expo eject”
},
“dependencies”: {
“expo”: “^32.0.0”,
“react”: “16.5.0”,
“react-native”: “https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz”
},
“devDependencies”: {
“babel-preset-expo”: “^5.0.0”
},
“private”: true,
“name”: “sample”,
“version”: “1.0.0”,
“author”: “Jahanmir”,
“license”: “ISC”,
“description”: “”
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked if you find it in your node_modules?
what I typically do in such case is delete the node_modules folder and run `npm install` which will re-install all node modules.

Comment: what this is telling you is, that git is not defined in the system path.
have you installed git?
if not please install git and afterwards see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows to add it to the path

Comment: @Defrain I did it, delete folder and run npm install expo-cli but again occur same error

Comment: can you try to open `cmd` Terminal an enter `git --version`

Comment: git version 2.20.1.windows.1

Comment: did the answer below solve the problem? if not: where can I find the complete error message?