# Error: unable to find git in your PATH on windows cmd

Tags: windows, git, flutter

I have followed all steps and added `C:\flutter\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe;C:\Windows\System32` to my path but still get the error `unable to find git in your PATH` after trying to run `flutter doctor`.

I have also reinstall Git and adjusted my PATH environment to use **Use Git and optional Unix tools from the command prompt** but I still get same error when trying to run `flutter doctor`

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263438/how-to-solve-unable-to-find-git-in-your-path-on-flutter

Comment: I just did, thanks for the help @Hamza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe`, you should add `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` to PATH.

When we type `git` and enter in `cmd.exe`, we actually run `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`.

`C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe` is a command line program that will initialize PATH and do other stuff. You still need to type `git` (short for `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`) to run git in git-cmd.exe.

Answer (score 12):

I've got this problem too when running `flutter doctor` on vs code cmd's, if you think you've added the correct PATH ([How to solve "Unable to find git in your PATH" on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263438/how-to-solve-unable-to-find-git-in-your-path-on-flutter)) and still get the error, try to run `git config --global --add safe.directory C:/flutter`. `C:/flutter` should be the directory of flutter that you use

Comment: `git config --global --add safe.directory C:/flutter` this work for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have installed new version from Git official website. (Git-2.41.0).

But the flutter has a git with different version: `2.15.1.windows.2.1.g603511c649`.
Maybe that could be the reason.

Steps I followed to solve my issue:

- Run command: `where git`. This will list out all the existing git paths.
- Remove all git entries except `C:\flutter\bin\mingit\cmd` from Environment Path variable. (If you don't have this variable, add it.).