# Error: Unable to find git in your PATH despite adding path and trying all available solutions

Tags: flutter, windows-11

I have been trying to install Flutter on Windows 11 and keep on getting stuck on

```
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH
```

I have been looking around and kept on trying different ways to get it to recognise the path but nothing seems to work:

- When installing git I made sure that the installer would add the path variables
- I added

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Git\bin
  C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
  ```

  to the user paths
- I also tried to add

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
  ```

  instead of just the folder (not actually sure which one is the better approach)

But none of this changed anything. I also tried to add

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

to the system variables but that gives me the error:

```
Error: PowerShell executable not found.
       Either pwsh.exe or PowerShell.exe must be in your PATH.
```

At this point I am out of ideas what else to do, I reinstalled git multiple times and restarted as well, always with the same result. Any help would be greatly appreciated

(also, when I type git --version I get git version 2.35.1.windows.2)

Comment: Open a DOS Window and do `PATH=C:\Program Files\git\bin;%PATH%` and then try to run `>git --version` does that work?

Comment: I also did a clean install and i am having this problem. none of those work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: unable to find git in your PATH on windows cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446923/error-unable-to-find-git-in-your-path-on-windows-cmd)

Comment: Checkout the Answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76495083/4061501

Answer (score 2):

the reason is that the flutter is mistakenly traversing into the **directory** that is of the **git** you have installed separately into your computer. When flutter is installed and its' path is given into environment variables, git that flutter has to access is already installed by it into /bin folder which is to be put inside Environment variables and the other default git has to be removed from environment variables or deleted from the computer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, where I was unable to run Flutter commands in my Windows Command Prompt even though I had Flutter and Git installed and updated to PATH in Environment Variables. I could run `git --version`, but when I issue the command `flutter --version` it said "unable to find git in PATH" and the terminal crashed.

Here is what solved the problem:

[image: flutter git path]

You have to add the `git cmd` path in the flutter folder i.e `C:\src\flutter\bin\mingit\cmd` as well as the one in the normal Git folder i.e `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` to the System Enviroment Variable PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like windows 11 needs to have the path of variables in Variables of Systems not users.
So, what I did was to add all the paths that where previously in System variables - users Path to system Path.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` to your environment variable "Path"?

It worked out when I added `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` along with flutter's bin folder, `C:\Windows\System32` , `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`, `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing this line in .gitconfig file :

[safe]

```
directory = mydir to flutter \\flutter
```

to :

```
directory = mydir to flutter /flutter
```

and worked for me !

Answer (score -1):

So this video has helped: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jrmxXtK_0k

I added to my system path variables:

1. the flutter bin file
2. C:\Windows\System32
3. C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
4. C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
5. C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

once all of those are added flutter does run in the console. I just have no idea it was needed when lots of other tutorials get along without it.