# error cloning my repository from github to RStudio

Tags: github, rstudio

I am trying to clone my repository from GitHub to Rstudio, however, I get the error in Rstudio:

```
 >>> C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe clone --progress https://github.com/cheryltky/covid19 https://github.com/cheryltky/covid19
fatal: could not create leading directories of 'https://github.com/cheryltky/covid19': Invalid argument
```

I am new to Github and Rstudio and tried using other people's comments to solve this but I have no idea what the comments mean. I am using a windows laptop and would love to have some step through help with this error. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, just to be clear, are you using the clone command like this?

`git clone --progress https://github.com/cheryltky/covid19/` 

Also can you add git to windows env variables/path , you can follow the steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26620861/13206920 for that. After that I can help you better

Comment: @Y4glory I followed the steps to clone a repository in RStudio based on this wesbite instructions : http://ohi-science.org/data-science-training/github.html#create-a-repository-on-github.com

Comment: I am trying to follow the instructions in the link you provided as well but getting myself in a knot at finding my "guid". Not sure where to look for this in my github account or what it means either. Thanks for your time/help, I really appreciate it as a zero coding/tech background person.

Comment: Don't worry about the guid . just use this link instead `C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe` for  step 1

Comment: Once you do that let me know

Comment: Also couldn't you use the instructions in the link provided for R(in the link you gave in your comment)? Because that would mean you don't have to install git to path.

Comment: I was such a numbwit. Found out my error in cloning the repository but all fixed up now! Thanks for the help though!