# RStudio Git Not Detected

Tags: r, windows, git, path, rstudio

Main Issue: RStudio > New Project > Version Control > Git states that Git was not detected on system path.

Overall, the main issue is that when I attempt to start a New Project under RStudio version control, it states that Git is not on my system path. This is the case despite manually setting the Git executable in Global Options. I can still access a Git-Bash terminal from RStudio and have successfully run basic git commands outlined in Happy With GitR Chapter 9 (https://happygitwithr.com/push-pull-github.html).

Other notes:

- Git version control still works in VSCode.
- `$ git` runs properly in RStudio in both a Git Bash terminal and Windows command prompt.
- At the end of installing Git, I received 12 error messages, ultimately stating that
  it was 'Unable to set system config defaults'

### Recreate Error Messages

- Run uninstall for current Git, manually delete any remaining files (usually `etc` folder)
- Download Git for Windows at https://gitforwindows.org/
- No changes to default settings during installer

### Attempted Fixes:

- Updated/Re-installed R and RStudio
- Updated/Re-installed Git
- Gone to Tools > Global Options > Git/SVN, manually set Git Executable  to `C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe`
- Followed Windows specific instructions at [Git: Installing Git in PATH with GitHub client for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows) (number 2 solution) by manually adding `C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe` and `C:/Program Files/Git/cmd` to my system PATH

### Additional Info:

- Windows machine running Windows 10

Comment: What RStudio version are you using? Where exactly is it telling you it's not on your system path? (Upload a screenshot to imgur might help) What does `Sys.which("git")` return in the Rstudio console? Or try `where git` in the Terminal window.

Comment: @MrFlick `Sys.which("git")` returns C:\\PROGRA~1\\Git\\bin\\git.exe. I am currenrly running the latest version of RStudio available at https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download  (1.2.5042 ). Missed this comment earlier, sorry for the much delayed response.

Comment: I have additional information about the issue posted here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-git-not-detected-git-tab-disappeared/62072

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem and tried everything you tried as well. This is what helped me in the end: re-agreeing to the xcode license agreement using `xcode-select --install` (I have MacOS though).

Source: https://happygitwithr.com/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting

Comment: Further discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522565/git-is-not-working-after-macos-update-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-pa