# How to execute a git command from Jenkins groovy on a windows agent?

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

The Jenkins node is a Windows agent, which has Git Bash installed.

I need to execute a git command inside a workspace folder that is already setup as a git folder. Due to the simplicity of the git command (say 'git branch'), we do not want to create an entire .sh file and opted for inline shell command like below.

```
//.groovy
dir ("c:/workspace/project@script/git-folder") {
  def git_cmd = sh(script: "git branch", returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

The above code works for our other linux nodes. However on this Windows node, Jenkins returned a Shell Script error **"c:/workspace/project@script/git-folder@tmp/durable-8xxxxx/script.sh: line 1: git: command not found"**

Why did it create the @tmp folder and executing the script inside there and not the intended folder? I checked the agent and looks like both "git-folder" and "git-folder@tmp" are in c:/workspace/ adjacently

I tried to remove the "dir" command and just cd into the path within the script as below

```
def git_cmd = sh(script: "cd c:/workspace/project@script/git-folder; git branch", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

but now the error is **"c:/workspace/project@2@tmp/durable-6xxxxx/script.sh: line 1: git: command not found"**

Found a [Jenkins issue thread](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52750?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) very similar to my problem, but no clear solution from that.

Comment: Looks like an issue with PATH on windows. Try specifying the full path to git.exe

Comment: @jordanm Where should I specifying it? The agent's environment variable, Jenkins config for the agent, or within the jenkinsfile itself?

Comment: `sh(script: "c/somedir/git.exe branch", returnStdout: true).trim()`

Comment: @jordanm Tried that, getting ".../git.exe: No such file or directory" error

Comment: Are you sure the git is inside the $PATH variable on the agent?

Comment: @S.Spieker Yes I added both ...Git\bin\ and Git\cmd\ into both system and user variables PATH

Comment: You can also try to explicitly point to the real exe file in your call, e.g. "c:\tools\git.exe branch"

Comment: @S.Spieker Isn't that what Jordanm suggested? I think that didn't work.

Comment: Have you done this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows