# Can commit to github

Tags: git

I prepared a project and would like to commit to Github. A also have Git + GitHub desktop and use VSCode and terminal in it.  So, when i try to check 'git' from the terminal in VSCode in folder with project i have the problem:

```
git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

When using common cmd all is OK! How could i fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+The+term+%27git%27+is+not+recognized+as+the+name+of+a+cmdlet%2C+function%2C+script+file%2C+or+operable+program

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `git` executable (`git.exe`) directory is not set up in the `PATH` variable, so PowerShell is unable to find it.

You need to locate the folder in which git is installed and add it in `PATH` using Windows' environment variables editor.

See detailed instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows).